# Color different parts of a RichTextBox string

Tags: c#, string, winforms, colors, richtextbox

I'm trying to color parts of a string to be appended to a RichTextBox. I have a string built from different strings.

```
string temp = "[" + DateTime.Now.ToShortTimeString() + "] " +
              userid + " " + message + Environment.NewLine;
```

This is what the message would look like once it is constructed.

> [9:23pm] User: my message here.

I want everything within and including the brackets [9:23] to be one color, 'user' to be another color and the message to be another color. Then I'd like the string appended to my RichTextBox.

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: dupe? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/455713/selectively-coloring-text-in-richtextbox

Comment: I did search and I have found none of it useful.

Comment: Thanks for this simple solution, works fine for me.
Don't forget to use the AppendText(...) every time you want to append text, and not use the '+=' operator or applied colors are discarded.

Answer (score 285, accepted):

Here is an extension method that overloads the `AppendText` method with a color parameter:

```
public static class RichTextBoxExtensions
{
    public static void AppendText(this RichTextBox box, string text, Color color)
    {
        box.SelectionStart = box.TextLength;
        box.SelectionLength = 0;

        box.SelectionColor = color;
        box.AppendText(text);
        box.SelectionColor = box.ForeColor;
    }
}
```

And this is how you would use it:

```
var userid = "USER0001";
var message = "Access denied";
var box = new RichTextBox
              {
                  Dock = DockStyle.Fill,
                  Font = new Font("Courier New", 10)
              };

box.AppendText("[" + DateTime.Now.ToShortTimeString() + "]", Color.Red);
box.AppendText(" ");
box.AppendText(userid, Color.Green);
box.AppendText(": ");
box.AppendText(message, Color.Blue);
box.AppendText(Environment.NewLine);

new Form {Controls = {box}}.ShowDialog();
```

Note that you may notice some flickering if you're outputting a lot of messages. See [this C# Corner](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/mgold/ColorSyntaxEditor12012005235814PM/ColorSyntaxEditor.aspx) article for ideas on how to reduce RichTextBox flicker.

Comment: I had some trouble with this. I used in another place `box.Text += mystring` and so all the colors disappeared. When I replaced this with `box.AppendText(mystring)`, it worked like a charme.

Comment: I have some trouble with the code the color dissapears on adding string in some other color.The only difference is i am assigning var box to a previously made richtextbox....

Comment: What am i doing wrong... "SelectionStart" is not a property of a RichTextBox (or i can't access it at least)?   I found "Selection" but it is a get-only property...

Comment: This is specifically for WinForms. Are you using WPF by any chance?

Comment: I have no overload ikee this, only `AppendText(string text)` with WinForms

Comment: @vaso123 **You have to _add it yourself._** (e.g. _Inside of a class file_)

Comment: Note that colors didn't work for me in the case where the form was not yet shown.

Answer (score 13):

I have expanded the method with font as a parameter:

```
public static void AppendText(this RichTextBox box, string text, Color color, Font font)
{
    box.SelectionStart = box.TextLength;
    box.SelectionLength = 0;

    box.SelectionColor = color;
    box.SelectionFont = font;
    box.AppendText(text);
    box.SelectionColor = box.ForeColor;
}
```

Comment: Note--for this to work you must use the AppendText method. Assigning anything to the text property of the box will break it.

Answer (score 13):

This is the modified version that I put in my code (I'm using .Net 4.5) but I think it should work on 4.0 too.

```
public void AppendText(string text, Color color, bool addNewLine = false)
{
    box.SuspendLayout();
    box.SelectionColor = color;
    box.AppendText(addNewLine
        ? $"{text}{Environment.NewLine}"
        : text);
    box.ScrollToCaret();
    box.ResumeLayout();
}
```

Differences with original one:

- Possibility to add text to a new line or simply append it
- No need to change selection, it works the same
- Inserted `ScrollToCaret` to force autoscroll
- Added [`SuspendLayout`/`ResumeLayout`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.suspendlayout?view=windowsdesktop-6.0) calls for better performance

Comment: Buggy for me - the first line of text was the wrong colour. See @boubkhaled 's answer (below atm) for a working version.

Comment: Well, the main difference between the two functions is that the latter allows you to decide whether or not to add a new line after the text, while the other always adds a new line (unless the RichTextBox is empty), the current date and time, and a tab character before the text. Also, the second function always sets the selection color to black after adding text, while the first function does not change the selection color after adding text (which is not required). I wouldn't call it buggy; it just needs to be used differently. To achieve the required result the other is not usable.

Comment: To be clear: to get exactly the result requested by the user who asked the question you have to make these three calls:  
AppendText($"[{DateTime.Now.ToShortTimeString()}] ", color_1);
AppendText($"{userid} ", color_2);
AppendText(message,color_3, true);   
You cannot get this result using the function proposed by @boubkhaled

Answer (score 7):

EDIT : sorry this is a WPF answer

I think modifying a "selected text" in a RichTextBox isn't the right way to add colored text.
So here a method to add a "color block" :

```
        Run run = new Run("This is my text");
        run.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red); // My Color
        Paragraph paragraph = new Paragraph(run);
        MyRichTextBlock.Document.Blocks.Add(paragraph);
```

From [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.richtextbox.blocks(v=vs.95).aspx) :

> The Blocks property is the content property of RichTextBox. It is a
> collection of Paragraph elements. Content in each Paragraph element
> can contain the following elements:
>
> - Inline
> - InlineUIContainer
> - Run
> - Span
> - Bold
> - Hyperlink
> - Italic
> - Underline
> - LineBreak

So I think you have to split your string depending on parts color, and create as many `Run` objects as needed.

Comment: I was hoping this was the answer I was really looking for, but it appears to be a WPF answer and not a WinForms answer.

Answer (score 2):

It`s work for me! I hope it will be useful to you!

```
public static RichTextBox RichTextBoxChangeWordColor(ref RichTextBox rtb, string startWord, string endWord, Color color)
{
    rtb.SuspendLayout();
    Point scroll = rtb.AutoScrollOffset;
    int slct = rtb.SelectionIndent;
    int ss = rtb.SelectionStart;
    List<Point> ls = GetAllWordsIndecesBetween(rtb.Text, startWord, endWord, true);
    foreach (var item in ls)
    {
        rtb.SelectionStart = item.X;
        rtb.SelectionLength = item.Y - item.X;
        rtb.SelectionColor = color;
    }
    rtb.SelectionStart = ss;
    rtb.SelectionIndent = slct;
    rtb.AutoScrollOffset = scroll;
    rtb.ResumeLayout(true);
    return rtb;
}

public static List<Point> GetAllWordsIndecesBetween(string intoText, string fromThis, string toThis,bool withSigns = true)
{
    List<Point> result = new List<Point>();
    Stack<int> stack = new Stack<int>();
    bool start = false;
    for (int i = 0; i < intoText.Length; i++)
    {
        string ssubstr = intoText.Substring(i);
        if (ssubstr.StartsWith(fromThis) && ((fromThis == toThis && !start) || !ssubstr.StartsWith(toThis)))
        {
            if (!withSigns) i += fromThis.Length;
            start = true;
            stack.Push(i);
        }
        else if (ssubstr.StartsWith(toThis) )
        {
            if (withSigns) i += toThis.Length;
            start = false;
            if (stack.Count > 0)
            {
                int startindex = stack.Pop();
                result.Add(new Point(startindex,i));
            }
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Selecting text as said from somebody, may the selection appear momentarily.
In `Windows Forms applications` there is no other solutions for the problem, but today I found a bad, working, way to solve: you can put a `PictureBox` in overlapping to the `RichtextBox` with the screenshot of if, during the selection and the changing color or font, making it after reappear all, when the operation is complete.

Code is here...

```
//The PictureBox has to be invisible before this, at creation
//tb variable is your RichTextBox
//inputPreview variable is your PictureBox
using (Graphics g = inputPreview.CreateGraphics())
{
    Point loc = tb.PointToScreen(new Point(0, 0));
    g.CopyFromScreen(loc, loc, tb.Size);
    Point pt = tb.GetPositionFromCharIndex(tb.TextLength);
    g.FillRectangle(new SolidBrush(Color.Red), new Rectangle(pt.X, 0, 100, tb.Height));
}
inputPreview.Invalidate();
inputPreview.Show();
//Your code here (example: tb.Select(...); tb.SelectionColor = ...;)
inputPreview.Hide();
```

Better is to use WPF; this solution isn't perfect, but for Winform it works.

Answer (score 1):

```
private void Log(string s , Color? c = null)
        {
            richTextBox.SelectionStart = richTextBox.TextLength;
            richTextBox.SelectionLength = 0;
            richTextBox.SelectionColor = c ?? Color.Black;
            richTextBox.AppendText((richTextBox.Lines.Count() == 0 ? "" : Environment.NewLine) + DateTime.Now + "\t" + s);
            richTextBox.SelectionColor = Color.Black;

        }
```

Answer (score 1):

I created this Function after researching on the internet since I wanted to print an XML string when you select a row from a data grid view.

```
static void HighlightPhrase(RichTextBox box, string StartTag, string EndTag, string ControlTag, Color color1, Color color2)
{
    int pos = box.SelectionStart;
    string s = box.Text;
    for (int ix = 0; ; )
    {
        int jx = s.IndexOf(StartTag, ix, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase);
        if (jx < 0) break;
        int ex = s.IndexOf(EndTag, ix, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase);
        box.SelectionStart = jx;
        box.SelectionLength = ex - jx + 1;
        box.SelectionColor = color1;
        
        int bx = s.IndexOf(ControlTag, ix, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase);
        int bxtest = s.IndexOf(StartTag, (ex + 1), StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase);
        if (bx == bxtest)
        {
            box.SelectionStart = ex + 1;
            box.SelectionLength = bx - ex + 1;
            box.SelectionColor = color2;
        }
        
        ix = ex + 1;
    }
    box.SelectionStart = pos;
    box.SelectionLength = 0;
}
```

and this is how you call it

```
   HighlightPhrase(richTextBox1, "<", ">","</", Color.Red, Color.Black);
```

Comment: This does not solve the given problem, only illustrates how the solution might work.

Answer (score 0):

Using Selection in WPF, aggregating from several other answers, no other code is required (except Severity enum and GetSeverityColor function)

```
 public void Log(string msg, Severity severity = Severity.Info)
    {
        string ts = "[" + DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm:ss") + "] ";
        string msg2 = ts + msg + "\n";
        richTextBox.AppendText(msg2);

        if (severity > Severity.Info)
        {
            int nlcount = msg2.ToCharArray().Count(a => a == '\n');
            int len = msg2.Length + 3 * (nlcount)+2; //newlines are longer, this formula works fine
            TextPointer myTextPointer1 = richTextBox.Document.ContentEnd.GetPositionAtOffset(-len);
            TextPointer myTextPointer2 = richTextBox.Document.ContentEnd.GetPositionAtOffset(-1);

            richTextBox.Selection.Select(myTextPointer1,myTextPointer2);
            SolidColorBrush scb = new SolidColorBrush(GetSeverityColor(severity));
            richTextBox.Selection.ApplyPropertyValue(TextElement.BackgroundProperty, scb);

        }

        richTextBox.ScrollToEnd();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I prepared a little helper for the RichTextBox control which makes it very easy to generate colored text on the screen:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Common.Helpers
{
    public class ColouredText
    {
        public string Text;
        public Color Foreground;
        public Color Background;

        public ColouredText(string text, Color foreground, Color background)
        {
            Text = text;
            Foreground = foreground;
            Background = background;
        }

        public ColouredText(string text, Color foreground) : this(text, foreground, Color.Transparent) { }

        public ColouredText(string text) : this(text, Color.Transparent, Color.Transparent) { }
    }

    public static class RichTextBoxHelper
    {
        private static RichTextBox _AppendText(RichTextBox box, string text, Color foreColor, Color backColor)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(text)) return box;

            box.SelectionStart = box.TextLength;
            box.SelectionLength = 0;

            box.SelectionColor = foreColor;
            box.SelectionBackColor = backColor;
            box.AppendText(text);
            box.SelectionColor = box.ForeColor;

            return box;
        }

        private static void _UpdateText(RichTextBox box, IEnumerable<ColouredText> newTextWithColors)
        {
            box.Text = "";

            foreach (var text in newTextWithColors)
            {
                var foreColor = text.Foreground; if (foreColor == Color.Transparent) foreColor = box.ForeColor;
                var backColor = text.Background; if (backColor == Color.Transparent) backColor = box.BackColor;

                _AppendText(box, text.Text, foreColor, backColor);
            }
        }

        public static void UpdateText(this RichTextBox richTextbox, IEnumerable<ColouredText> text)
        {
            if (richTextbox.InvokeRequired) richTextbox.Invoke((MethodInvoker)(() => { _UpdateText(richTextbox, text); }));
            else _UpdateText(richTextbox, text);
        }

        public static void UpdateText(this RichTextBox richTextbox, ColouredText text)
        {
            var list = new List<ColouredText>() { text };

            if (richTextbox.InvokeRequired) richTextbox.Invoke((MethodInvoker)(() => { _UpdateText(richTextbox, list); }));
            else _UpdateText(richTextbox, list);
        }
    }
}
```

and now you can use:

```
var text = new List<ColouredText>()
{
    new ColouredText($"text#1    ", Color.Black),
    new ColouredText($"text#2    ", Color.Red, Color.Yellow),
    new ColouredText($" "),
    new ColouredText($"text#2    ", Color.White, Color.Black)
};

richTextBox1.UpdateText(text);
```

or simpler usage for single-line text:

```
richTextBox1.UpdateText(new ColouredText($"warning message", Color.Yellow, Color.Red));
```