# WPF RichTextBox appending coloured text

Tags: c#, wpf, colors, richtextbox

I'm using the `RichTextBox.AppendText` function to add a string to my `RichTextBox`. I'd like to set this with a particular colour. How can I do this?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Just try this:

```
TextRange tr = new TextRange(rtb.Document.ContentEnd,­ rtb.Document.ContentEnd);
tr.Text = "textToColorize";
tr.ApplyPropertyValue(TextElement.­ForegroundProperty, Brushes.Red);
```

Answer (score 21):

If you want, you can also make it an extension method.

```
public static void AppendText(this RichTextBox box, string text, string color)
{
    BrushConverter bc = new BrushConverter();
    TextRange tr = new TextRange(box.Document.ContentEnd, box.Document.ContentEnd);
    tr.Text = text;
    try 
    { 
        tr.ApplyPropertyValue(TextElement.ForegroundProperty, 
            bc.ConvertFromString(color)); 
    }
    catch (FormatException) { }
}
```

This will make it so you can just do

```
myRichTextBox.AppendText("My text", "CornflowerBlue");
```

or in hex such as

```
myRichTextBox.AppendText("My text", "0xffffff");
```

If the color string you type is invalid, it simply types it in the default color (black).
Hope this helps!

Comment: The color change remains in effect for text added with subsequent calls to the built-in `AppendText(text)` method. It might be better if the appended-text color was reset to the control's Foreground. (See the [WinForms version](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1926822/294248).)

Answer (score 7):

### Be Aware of TextRange's Overhead

I spent a lot of time tearing my hair out, because `TextRange` wasn't fast enough for my use-case. This method avoids the overhead. I ran some barebones tests, and its faster by a factor of ~10 *(but don't take my word for it lol, run your own tests)*

```
Paragraph paragraph = new Paragraph();
Run run = new Run("MyText");
paragraph.Inlines.Add(run);
myRichTextBox.Document.Blocks.Add(paragraph);
```

[Credit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27524030/how-to-append-rtf-text-in-richtextbox-in-wpf-with-c-sharp)

**Note:**  I think most use cases should work fine with `TextRange`. My use-case involved hundreds of individual appends, and that overhead stacks up.

Comment: Is there a way to color the Run though (as the question asks)?

Comment: `run.Background = Brushes.Green; run.Foreground = Brushes.Red;`

Comment: This solution will not append text to the end of the current line. Instead, it will add a blank empty line and start the message on the next new line. If you need a solution that respects line breaks, please look at [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76662829/7585517)

Answer (score 4):

Just a complete example which mixes original question with previous remark from Tony

```cs
var paragraph = new Paragraph();
var run = new Run(message)    
{
    Foreground = someBrush
};
paragraph.Inlines.Add(run);
myRichTextBox.Document.Blocks.Add(paragraph);
```

Now, it is fast and coloured :)

*Note that (unlike the TextRange solution) this solution also solved me a line break issue occurring at the first line of the RichTextBox.*

Answer (score 0):

I ended up synthesising Omni and Kishores' answers and creating an extension method as so:

```
public static void AppendText(this System.Windows.Controls.RichTextBox box, string text, SolidColorBrush brush)
{
    TextRange tr = new TextRange(box.Document.ContentEnd, box.Document.ContentEnd);
    tr.Text = text;
    tr.ApplyPropertyValue(TextElement.ForegroundProperty, brush);
}
```

Which can be called as so:

```
MyTextBox.AppendText("Some Text\n", Brushes.Green);
```

Answer (score 0):

I have further improved [@Jack's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5512921/wpf-richtextbox-appending-coloured-text/66665895#66665895):

- Allow a user to pass front and background text colors
- Add a workaround to make the code work properly in case a message contains line break symbols.

**Code**

```
private void AppendText(RichTextBox textBox,
                        string message,
                        SolidColorBrush fontColor,
                        SolidColorBrush backgroundColor)
{
    // If a message contains line breaks, the code bellow will
    // add an empty blank line for every line break in the message.
    // To avoid that we have to replace all new lines in the mesage with '\r' symbol.
    message = Regex.Replace(message, @"(\r\n)|(\n\r)|(\n)", "\r");

    var textRange = new TextRange(textBox.Document.ContentEnd,
                                  textBox.Document.ContentEnd) { Text = message };
    textRange.ApplyPropertyValue(TextElement.ForegroundProperty, fontColor);
    textRange.ApplyPropertyValue(TextElement.BackgroundProperty, backgroundColor);
}
```

**Demo**

The following code will display the messages, taking into account new line symbols:

```
AppendText(_richTextBox, "First part of the line. ", Brushes.Green, Brushes.Yellow);
AppendText(_richTextBox, "Second part of the line. ", Brushes.Blue, Brushes.White);
AppendText(_richTextBox, "Third part that\ncontains new line in the middle\n", Brushes.LightPink, Brushes.Gray);
AppendText(_richTextBox, "New line\nNew line\nNew line", Brushes.Black, Brushes.White);
```

[image]

Answer (score -2):

the above single line answer:-

```
  myRichTextBox.AppendText("items", "CornflowerBlue")
```

is not working.The correct way it should be writen is (i am using VS 2017) :-

```
    Dim text1 As New TextRange(myRichTextBox.Document.ContentStart, myRichTextBox.Document.ContentEnd)
  myRichTextBox.AppendText("items")
  text1.ApplyPropertyValue(TextElement.ForegroundProperty, Brushes.CornflowerBlue)
```

Comment: If this was in response to my above answer, you must also include the extension method definition to use it.

Comment: you did not grasp that omni created an extension method that allows passing a color name