# How to append RTF text in richtextbox in WPF with C#

Tags: c#, wpf

I have string of RTF and want to append that RTF in other `RichTextBox` I am using `richtextbox1.AppendText(RTFString);` but that appending all the text without styling the text

```
string RTFString = {\rtf1\ansi\ansicpg1252\uc1\htmautsp\deff2{\fonttbl{\f0\fcharset0 Times New Roman;}        {\f2\fcharset0 Segoe UI;}{\f3\fcharset0 Blackadder ITC;}}{\colortbl\red0\green0\blue0;\red255\green255\blue255;}\loch\hich\dbch\pard\plain\ltrpar\itap0{\lang1033\fs21\f2\cf0 \cf0\ql\sl20\slmult0{\fs108\f3 {\ltrch uzair}\li0\ri0\sa0\sb0\fi0\ql\sl20\slmult0\par}
}

}{\rtf1\ansi{\fonttbl\f0\fswiss Helvetica;}\f0\pard \{\\rtf1\\ansi\\ansicpg1252\\uc1\\htmautsp\\deff2\{\\fonttbl\{\\f0\\fcharset0 Times New Roman;\}\{\\f2\\fcharset0 Segoe UI;\}\{\\f3\\fcharset0 Blackadder ITC;\}\}\{\\colortbl\\red0\\green0\\blue0;\\red255\\green255\\blue255;\}\\loch\\hich\\dbch\\pard\\plain\\ltrpar\\itap0\{\\lang1033\\fs21\\f2\\cf0 \\cf0\\ql\\sl20\\slmult0\{\\fs108\\f3 \{\\ltrch uzair\}\\li0\\ri0\\sa0\\sb0\\fi0\\ql\\sl20\\slmult0\\par\} \par \} \par \} }
```

**Appending**

```
richtextBox1.AppendText(RTFString);
```

**Output**

```
Same as the "RTFString" text
```

**Optional**
While styling fontFamily, if the fontFamily have fallback setting it will be great

Comment: what do you mean by styling? font ?

Comment: I am sending this string to other computer using tcp so the other computer may or may not have the same font I used in my computer so it should automatically fallback to arial

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
FlowDocument document = new FlowDocument();
Paragraph paragraph = new Paragraph();
paragraph.Inlines.Add(new Bold(new Run("Your text")));
document.Blocks.Add(paragraph);
richTextBox1.Document = document;
```

Use Paragraph class and add it as a document. Hope it will help.

EDIT

If you talk about rtf text then try this

```
MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(ASCIIEncoding.Default.GetBytes(text));
this.mainRTB.Selection.Load(stream, DataFormats.Rtf);
```

Comment: Nope Its still adding text like this `{\rtf1\ansi\ansicpg1252\uc1\ ...`