# Multi-color TextBox C#

Tags: c#, winforms, textbox

I want show text in textbox in 2 colors, for example 1 line red 2 blue, if I use `name.ForeColor = Color.Red;` all text change color, but I want that will change only 1 line color.

Comment: @Tudor ForeColor is a windows forms property

Comment: You could take a look at NLog's richtextbox custom target source. Especially if you need this for logging :P

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You need to use a [RichTextBox](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.richtextbox.aspx).

You can then change the textcolor by selecting text and changing the selection color or font.

```
richTextBox1.SelectionFont = new Font("Verdana", 12, FontStyle.Bold);
richTextBox1.SelectionColor = Color.Red;
```

Comment: Any way without **RichTextBox**? It's really slow when there are too many words to iterate.

Answer (score 55):

Use a RichTextBox for that, here is an extension method by Nathan Baulch

```
public static class RichTextBoxExtensions
{
    public static void AppendText(this RichTextBox box, string text, Color color)
    {
        box.SelectionStart = box.TextLength;
        box.SelectionLength = 0;

        box.SelectionColor = color;
        box.AppendText(text);
        box.SelectionColor = box.ForeColor;
    }
}
```

Read more [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1926264/color-different-parts-of-a-richtextbox-string)

Comment: any idea how to do with textbox ?

Comment: there is no way to do that with a wf TextBox , you will either have to creat your own UserControl or use the RichTextBox...

Comment: I'm now studying your code `var userid = "USER0001";
var message = "Access denied";
var box = new RichTextBox
              {
                  Dock = DockStyle.Fill,
                  Font = new Font("Courier New", 10)
              };

box.AppendText("[" + DateTime.Now.ToShortTimeString() + "]", Color.Red);
box.AppendText(" ");
box.AppendText(userid, Color.Green);
box.AppendText(": ");
box.AppendText(message, Color.Blue);
box.AppendText(Environment.NewLine);

new Form {Controls = {box}}.ShowDialog();` and not understand how to do that RichTextBox will be not in new form ?

Comment: that is not my code, simply add  the extension method to your project by pasting it to a new file. Add a RichTextBox control and use the AppendText method.

Comment: ok, but `new Form {Controls = {box}}.ShowDialog();' I not need show in new form, how to call this method not using new form

Comment: I think he's talking about [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1926822/8524922)

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example with a Fontdialog and Colordialog.

```
void TextfarbeToolStripMenuItemClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            colorDialog1.ShowDialog();
            richTextBox1.ForeColor = colorDialog1.Color;
            listBox1.ForeColor = colorDialog1.Color;
        }

        void FontsToolStripMenuItemClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            fontDialog1.ShowDialog();
            richTextBox1.Font = fontDialog1.Font;
            listBox1.Font = fontDialog1.Font;
        }

        void HintergrundfarbeToolStripMenuItemClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            colorDialog1.ShowDialog();
            richTextBox1.BackColor = colorDialog1.Color;
            listBox1.BackColor = colorDialog1.Color;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, the details + tags you provided are not sufficient - C# doesn't have one specific UI framework, it has a few: WPF, Winforms, ASP.NET, Silverlight.

Second of all, you can not do this with a regular textbox control in any of the above.
You will need to find/create a custom UI control which has a different behaviour or use a more advanced control e.g. a rich text box.