# How to use multi color in richtextbox

Tags: c#, .net, richtextbox

I using C# windows forms and I have richtextbox and I want to color some text in red, some in green and some in black.

How to do so? Image attached.

[image]

Comment: Some code that shows what you already did would be helpful.

Comment: @PaulHiemstra Indeed I'm a C++, C, Java, Assembly and more langs programmer, I had never used C# before. I take a course in the collage about C#. 'Till I'll get in the business , I might need your help. thank you for listening.

Comment: I hope here the solution you are looking for 

http://stackoverflow.com/a/27149285/998483

Answer (score 35, accepted):

`System.Windows.Forms.RichTextBox` has got a property of type `Color` of the name `SelectionColor` which gets or sets the text color of the current selection or insertion point. You can use this property to mark specific fields in your `RichTextBox` with the colors you specify.

**Example**

```
RichTextBox _RichTextBox = new RichTextBox(); //Initialize a new RichTextBox of name _RichTextBox
_RichTextBox.Select(0, 8); //Select text within 0 and 8
_RichTextBox.SelectionColor = Color.Red; //Set the selected text color to Red
_RichTextBox.Select(8, 16); //Select text within 8 and 16
_RichTextBox.SelectionColor = Color.Green; //Set the selected text color to Green
_RichTextBox.Select(0,0); //Select text within 0 and 0
```

**Notice that**: You may avoid calculations by using `RichTextBox.Find(string str)` which can be added through `Object Browser` if you would like to highlight the text within the `Lines` in `RichTextBox` giving it's value

<sup>**Example**</sup>

```
RichTextBox _RichTextBox = new RichTextBox(); //Initialize a new RichTextBox of name _RichTextBox
_RichTextBox.Find("Account 12345, deposit 100$, balance 200$"); //Find the text provided
_RichTextBox.SelectionColor = Color.Green; //Set the selected text color to Green
```

Thanks,

I hope you find this helpful :)

Comment: This is a working solution but there is an easyer way to proceed : http://stackoverflow.com/a/10587765/1529139

Answer (score 13):

I found this extension method that gives you the ability to change the color of the string as well as inserting a newline value:

```
    public static void AppendText(this RichTextBox box, string text, Color color, bool AddNewLine = false)
    {
        if (AddNewLine)
        {
            text += Environment.NewLine;
        }

        box.SelectionStart = box.TextLength;
        box.SelectionLength = 0;

        box.SelectionColor = color;
        box.AppendText(text);
        box.SelectionColor = box.ForeColor;
    }
```

Comment: I think you can also add `box.SuspendLayout()` at the beginning of the method and `box.ResumeLayout()` at the end.

Answer (score -1):

you can use Run object to change the color at runtime

```
private Run GetForegroundColor(string strInformation, Brush color)
        {
            Run noramlRun = new Run(strInformation);
            noramlRun.Foreground = color;
            return noramlRun;
        }
```

for more complex scenario like change the color based on requirement then visit blow link

https://sites.google.com/site/greateindiaclub/mobil-apps/windows8/customwpfrichtextboxwithcolorchangeandhighlightfunctionality