# Selecting text and changing it's color on a line of a RichTextBox

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, foreach, richtextbox, appendtext

Good Afternoon.  I am new to stack overflow as a poster but have referenced it for years.  I have been researching this problem of mine for about 2 weeks and while I've seen solutions that are close I still am left with an issue.

I am writing a C# gui that reads in an assembly code file and highlights different text items for further processing via another program.  My form has a RichTextBox that the text is displayed in.  In the case below I am trying to select the text at the location of the ‘;’ until the end of the line and change the text to color red.  Here is the code that I am using.

Please note:  The files that are read in by the program are of inconsistent length, not all lines are formatted the same so I cannot simply search for the ';' and operate on that.

On another post a member has given an extension method for AppendText which I have gotten to work perfectly except for the original text is still present along with my reformatted text.  Here is the link to that site:
[How to use multi color in richtextbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13220856/how-to-use-multi-color-in-richtextbox)

```
// Loop that it all runs in
Foreach (var line in inArray)
{   

  // getting the index of the ‘;’ assembly comments
  int cmntIndex = line.LastIndexOf(';');

  // getting the index of where I am in the rtb at this time.  
  int rtbIndex = rtb.GetFirstCharIndexOfCurrentLine();

  // just making sure I have a valid index
  if (cmntIndex != -1)
  {
    // using rtb.select to only select the desired 
    // text but for some reason I get it all    
    rtb.Select(cmntIndex + rtbIndex, rtb.SelectionLength);
    rtb.SelectionColor = Color.Red;
  }
}
```

Below is the sample assembly code from a file in it's original form all the text is black:

```
;;TAG SOMETHING, SOMEONE START                          
    ASSEMBLY CODE       ; Assembly comments
    ASSEMBLY CODE       ; Assembly comments
    ASSEMBLY CODE       ; Assembly comments
;;TAG SOMETHING, SOMEONE FINISH
```

When `rtb.GetFirstCharIndexOfCurrentLine()` is called it returns a valid index of the RTB and I imagine that if I add the value returned by `line.LastIndexOf(';')` I will then be able to just select the text above that looks like `; Assembly comments` and turn it red.

What does happen is that the entire line turns red.

When I use the AppendText method above I get

`ASSEMBLY CODE (this is black)      ; Assembly comments (this is red)    (the rest is black)    ASSEMBLY CODE       ; Assembly comments`

The black code is the exact same code as the recolored text.  In this case I need to know how to clear the line in the RTB and/or overwrite the text there.  All the options that I have tried result in deletion of those lines.

Anywho, I'm sure that was lengthy but I'm really stumped here and would greatly appreciate advice.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to select text from the RichTextBox and then color it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3707120/how-to-select-text-from-the-richtextbox-and-then-color-it)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hope I've understood you correctly.

This loops over each line in the `richtextbox`, works out which lines are the assembly comments, then makes everything red after the ";"

**With FOREACH loop as requested**

To use a foreach loop you simply need to keep track of the index manually like so:

```
// Index
int index = 0;

// Loop over each line
foreach (string line in richTextBox1.Lines)
{
    // Ignore the non-assembly lines
    if (line.Substring(0, 2) != ";;")
    {
        // Start position
        int start = (richTextBox1.GetFirstCharIndexFromLine(index) + line.LastIndexOf(";") + 1);

        // Length
        int length = line.Substring(line.LastIndexOf(";"), (line.Length - (line.LastIndexOf(";")))).Length;

        // Make the selection
        richTextBox1.SelectionStart = start;
        richTextBox1.SelectionLength = length;

        // Change the colour
        richTextBox1.SelectionColor = Color.Red;
    }

    // Increase index
    index++;
}
```

**With FOR loop**

```
// Loop over each line
for(int i = 0; i < richTextBox1.Lines.Count(); i++)
{
    // Current line text
    string currentLine = richTextBox1.Lines[i];

    // Ignore the non-assembly lines
    if (currentLine.Substring(0, 2) != ";;")
    {
        // Start position
        int start = (richTextBox1.GetFirstCharIndexFromLine(i) + currentLine.LastIndexOf(";") + 1);

        // Length
        int length = currentLine.Substring(currentLine.LastIndexOf(";"), (currentLine.Length - (currentLine.LastIndexOf(";")))).Length;

        // Make the selection
        richTextBox1.SelectionStart = start;
        richTextBox1.SelectionLength = length;

        // Change the colour
        richTextBox1.SelectionColor = Color.Red;
    }
}
```

[image: Example of red highlighted richtext]

**Edit:**

Re-reading your question I'm confused as to whether you wanted to make the ; red as well.

If you do remove the +1 from this line:

```
int start = (richTextBox1.GetFirstCharIndexFromLine(i) + currentLine.LastIndexOf(";") + 1);
```

Comment: Thanks for the help.  Only because im taking this project over from another coder is there any way to keep the foreach?

Comment: Updated answer that shows both loops. Both work the same, I just felt that a FOR loop had a clearer syntax. Hope it helps :-)

Comment: Thanks so much for the help!  What I have found is that when I execute `richtextbox1.selectionlength = length` or `richtextbox1.selectionlength = 22` (22 is just a number) while watching it selectionlength always gets set to zero.  Any idea why that is happening?  I have FIPS disabled could it have anything to do with that?

Comment: Pardon my ignorance, but what is FIPS? I thought it was something to do with encryption which I'm not sure is relevant here. Are you saying that this code doesn't work for you? It should work on every line that doesn't begin with ;; and set everything after the last instance of a ; to red. If the line doesn't contain a ; it wouldn't work, but you only provided limited text in your sample so I couldn't make it more robust. I take it the sample you're now using contains a lot more text than you originally showed?

Comment: Equalsk, The code works.  Yes FIPS is for encryption but it's turned off and I didn't know if it also messed with anything else. Say `length = 24` While in debug mode when I'm executing `rtb1.selectionlength = length` instead of selectionlength property getting set to 24 it always gets set to zero.  Even when I hard code a number instead of `length` it still gets set to zero.  What happens when this occurs is the entire line turns red.  Is that more clear?  Yes there are a great deal more lines instead of the simple ones I put as an example but the format is the same.

Comment: I don't know why that would happen. Your best option is to close this question and raise another one. You'll get a quicker response this way and hopefully someone has seen this behaviour before and can answer for you. Sorry I can't be of more help!

Comment: Sorry for the delay work has been tasking me heavily.  The code I'm using and what is posted above seems to be correct.  I'm moving on with the project and will re-attack this at the end.  If I find out why it is happening i'll post the reason.  Thanks for all your help!

Answer (score 1):

```
Private Sub RichTextBox1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles RichTextBox1.Click
    Dim MyInt1 As Integer
    Dim MyInt2 As Integer
    ' Reset your RTB back color to white at each click
    RichTextBox1.SelectionBackColor = Color.White
    ' Define the nth first character number of the line you clicked
    MyInt1 = RichTextBox1.GetFirstCharIndexOfCurrentLine()
    ' use that nth to find the line number in the RTB
    MyInt2 = RichTextBox1.GetLineFromCharIndex(MyInt1)
    'Select the line using an array property of RTB (RichTextBox1.Lines())
    RichTextBox1.Select(MyInt1, RichTextBox1.Lines(MyInt2).Length)
    ' This line would be for font color change : RichTextBox1.SelectionColor = Color.Maroon
    ' This one changes back color :
    RichTextBox1.SelectionBackColor = Color.Yellow
End Sub
```

' There are a few bugs inherent to the rtb.select method
' It bugs if a line wraps, or fails on an "http" line... probably more.
(I just noticed the default stackoverflow.com character colors on my above code are not correct for comment lines and others.)