# Read only textbox with different text colors?

Tags: vb.net

I've been wondering this question for a while and my friend recommended me this website, so yeah, I'm new here.
I'm trying to learn VB.net but I've found nothing about this. Can anyone help me?

I have a textbox which is read only. Inside the textbox, I have text that says "Checking" (in blue letters)
This waits about 20 seconds usually, and then below it it says either "Completed" (green text) or "Failed" (red text) while the checking still remains blue.

Is there a way to do this? Sorry that I'm not explaining stuff the best but I just need help.
Thank you!

Comment: Please provide code what have you tried so far to do your query?

Comment: why don't you just use labels? are you going to use that textbox later for inputs?

Comment: You'd have to use something like a `RichTextBox` to accomplish this. See this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13220856/how-to-use-multi-color-in-richtextbox

Comment: I'm attempting to make an output sort of thing which will have more inputs in the future.

Answer (score 0):

it will be awesome if you tell us what you actually want to accomplish, since it is not very specific but what I understood you want to wait for 20 seconds for something to be accomplished, so I will recommend [System.Threading.Thread.Sleep](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d00bd51t.aspx) and there should be a method that allows you to know your process is ready to go. to change the color lblGrade.ForeColor = Color.Orange should do the trick.

Comment: I'm making a program that helps users with shortcuts for certain games. I'm trying to add an output if anything goes wrong, and I want the text to be multi colored.