# RichTextBox select par of text

Tags: c#, textbox

I have `RichTextBox`. How I can select there text between `/*` and `*/` and make this text green color?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14085607/textbox-text-color-change

Comment: Do you want to think about something yourself or are you going to ask everything here? What have you tried?

Comment: @sa_ddam213 thats his own question

Comment: The content of the RichTextbox is a [`FlowDocument`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.documents.flowdocument.aspx). You may want to start there and with this [MSDN Forum Post](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wpf/thread/01c9faac-2c37-40ca-9ca5-91d433033671/)

Comment: Since, you haven't given any info in the way you wan't to do it, this small piece code would give you an idea; This is in WPF `string searchFor = "/*" + textBox4.Text + "*/";
            var finalvalue = searchFor.Trim( new Char[] { '/', '*' } );
            textBox4.Foreground = Brushes.Green;`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5442067/change-color-and-font-for-some-part-of-text-in-wpf-c-sharp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
string text = "abc /*defg*/ hij /*klm*/ xyz";
richTextBox1.Text = text;

Regex.Matches(text, @"\/\*(.*?)\*\/",RegexOptions.Singleline).Cast<Match>()
        .ToList()
        .ForEach(m =>
        {
            richTextBox1.Select(m.Index, m.Value.Length);
            richTextBox1.SelectionColor = Color.Blue;
            //or 
            //richTextBox1.Select(m.Groups[1].Index, m.Groups[1].Value.Length);
            //richTextBox1.SelectionColor = Color.Blue;
        });
```