# How To Use MultiColor Line In RichTextBox in VB.net WinForm?

Tags: vb.net, richtextbox

i read [multi-color-textbox-c-sharp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10587715/multi-color-textbox-c-sharp) and some other like these in here.but i want to use multicolor in One line.For example if my string in line is "Hi,I am a string here", i want to "Hi,I am" in red and " a string here" in blue color.like this  >> [image]

Can any body help me please on this?

Comment: Set the SelectionStart and SelectionEnd properties to select the text fragment.  Then assign the SelectionColor property.   Easy peasy.

Comment: but it just usefull for one line...what if i use multi lines?

Answer (score 0):

How about this, hope it helps

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/865b510b-a67e-4b20-b762-4c8935db0f56/change-texts-color-in-rich-text-box-similar-to-what-visual-studio-does?forum=vblanguage