# RichTextBox does not contain definition for almost everything

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

So today I tried to give my nice console logs a cool color using a richtextbox.
But the code has a lot of errors

```
    RichTextBox box = ConsoleTextBox;

    box.SelectionStart = box.TextLength;
    box.SelectionLength = 0;

    box.SelectionColor = color;
    box.AppendText(text);
    box.SelectionColor = box.ForeColor;
```

I get an error on SelectionStart, TextLength, SelectionLength, SlectionColor and ForeColor.
The error says:

> RichTextBox does not contain a definition for 'one of the above' and
>   no extension method 'one of the above'

This is my XAML:

```
<Grid>
    <RichTextBox Name="ConsoleTextBox"
                 AcceptsReturn="True"
                 ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
                 Background="#FF0d0d0d"
                 Foreground="White"
                 BorderBrush="#FF282828"
                 BorderThickness="0,1,0,0">
    </RichTextBox>
</Grid>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The properties which you tried to access belongs to a normal text box not a rich textbox

Comment: @Joseph how can you explain this then? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10587715/multi-color-textbox-c-sharp

Comment: @ Bitsec the question relates to what WPF or Win forms?

Answer (score -1):

As per the [Rich TextBox Class reference in MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.richtextbox(v=vs.110).aspx), it doesn't have definitions for SelectionStart, TextLength, SelectionLength, SelectionColor and ForeColor.

So I would like to suggest you to use a normal TextBox([See MSDN reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.textbox(v=vs.110).aspx)) to use features like `SelectioNStart`, `SelectionLength`, `Foreground` etc or create a custom control derived from `TextBox` class to achieve the desired appearance or functionality.