# Best way to create multiple lines with different colors

Tags: powershell, fonts, textbox, label, multiline

I am trying to figure out, what is the best way, to output multi-lines with different colors.
There are several options that I have but each of them is challenging in some way. The possibilities I assume I have are:

- Listbox
- Textbox
- Label

I am building a vocabulary trainer, where during a test, you have to write words. At the end of the test, I would like to summarize the test.

The first challenge is, that the test are different in length, meaning it can be a test of only 10 words or more. The target is, to show to each question the answer and analyze if it is correct and wrong and if wrong, where it went wrong. That part I have solved.

But now the question is, how to present the results.

Listbox and Textbox are surely easier to handle but if I understand correctly, there will be a challenge with the output having different colors.

Label would be easier to handle but there I am struggling with Multiline and so far, the only solution I have so far is to generate for each result a different label, which means, I have to build labels according to the sum of the output, meaning 10 test questions would require 10 Labels.

When you run the test script below, you will see as a result, you wrote: Where the mistake is shown with a red-letter.

The idea would be, to have such output for each line, where the mistake is shown and if correct, it has a green color, to show, it is all ok.

```
Clear-Host

$Frage = 'Hello World'
$Antwort = 'Hello Warld'
$Script:Counter = 0
$wordlength = $Frage.Length

Do {
    if ($Antwort[$Script:Counter] -ne $Frage[$Script:Counter]) { break }
    Write-Host $Frage[$Script:Counter] -NoNewline;
    Write-Host -ForegroundColor Red '    '$Antwort[$Script:Counter]
    $Script:Counter++

} # End of 'Do'
Until ($Script:Counter -eq $wordlength)

If ($Antwort.Length -gt $Frage.Length) {

    $TooShortDifference = $Antwort[($Frage.Length)..($Antwort.Length)]
    Write-Host ''
    Write-Host -ForegroundColor Red 'Your Answer has too many letters'
    Write-Host '' 
    Write-Host -ForegroundColor Green -NoNewline 'You wrote:     ' 
    Write-Host $Firstpart -NoNewline;
    Write-Host $TooShortDifference -ForegroundColor Red 
    Write-Host ''
    Write-Host -ForegroundColor Green -NoNewline 'The answer is: '
    Write-Host -ForegroundColor White $Frage
    Write-Host ''
}

Elseif ($Antwort.Length -lt $Frage.Length) {

    $TooLongDifference = $Frage[($Antwort.Length)..$Frage.Length]
    Write-Host ''
    Write-Host -ForegroundColor Red 'Your Answer has not enough letters'
    Write-Host '' 
    Write-Host -ForegroundColor Green -NoNewline 'You wrote:     ' 
    Write-Host -ForegroundColor White $Antwort
    Write-Host ''
    Write-Host -ForegroundColor Green -NoNewline 'The answer is: '
    Write-Host -ForegroundColor White $Antwort -NoNewline
    Write-Host -ForegroundColor Red $TooLongDifference -Separator ''
}

Elseif ($Antwort.Length -eq $Frage.Length) {

    $SameLengthWithError = $Frage[0..($Script:Counter - 1)]
    Write-Host ''
    Write-Host -ForegroundColor Red 'Your Answer has a letter mismatch'
    Write-Host ''
    Write-Host -ForegroundColor White 'You Wrote:     ' -NoNewline
    Write-Host $SameLengthWithError -NoNewline -Separator ''
    Write-Host $Antwort[$Script:Counter] -ForegroundColor Red  -NoNewline
    Write-Host $Antwort[($Script:Counter + 1)..$Antwort.Length] -Separator ''
    Write-Host ''
    Write-Host -ForegroundColor Green 'The Answer is: ' -NoNewline
    Write-Host -ForegroundColor Green $Frage

}

Else {

    Write-Host -ForegroundColor Green 'Everything was correct'
}
```

If you would build something similar, which way would you use and how would you show multiple lines, where within the font colors would change on each line?

Comment: Have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10587766/9898643). I think you want to use a RichTextbox

Comment: Hello Theo, that could work. I need to study and understand this, but it looks promising, thanx a lot