# Is there any way to find and highlight text in RichTextBlock?

Tags: c#, winrt-xaml

I develop an app for Windows 8 with long text content. For displaying content I use RichTextBlock. I need to implement "Find on Page" functionality, but I can't find anything to do it.

What I have already tried to use:

1. WinRtXamlToolkit and HighlightBehavior - only works with TextBlock
2. RichTextBlock.Select()

Does anyone have any ideas how to do it?

Comment: Hi! Did you find a solution?

Answer (score -1):

You can add various formats to text within RichTextBoxes. I've found an answer about [coloring parts of text within RichTextBoxes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1926264/color-different-parts-of-a-richtextbox-string). I would take the following steps:

1. Adapt/implement the code from the answer mentioned above
2. Check whether the search string is within the target string
3. Replace the text within the RichtTextBox with the text before the search string, then the colored search string, and lastly the text appearing after the search string

I assume this can also be done with a highlight instead of a colored font.

Comment: I use **RichTextBlock** not RichTextBox.