# TextBox with multiple font colors

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-7, windows-8, windows-phone-8

I would like to develop something like a text Editor for Windows Phone but I faced several problems during the design process. What I basically need is a control that not only allows me to type in text but also lets me draw the text in that TextBox in different colors, just like in Microsoft Office for Windows Phone. 
As far as I know the TextBox control does not support font coloring. I tried using the  tags but unfortunately this does not work. My question now is if there is a way to have a TextBox that lets me color different parts of the text in different colors. I am thinking about creating a custom control but how would I implement such a feature?

Comment: richtextbox was ported from silverlight to Windows phone and it misses many features like copy and paste.

Comment: @sourabhdevpura: "In this release of Silverlight for Windows Phone, RichTextBox is read-only". Hmm... nice **editor**.

Comment: dup of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1926264/color-different-parts-of-a-richtextbox-string

Answer (score 1):

you can not do it directly as these is not a feature present in windows phone to keep multiple font colors in a single control. You would have to make a custom control which complies over your needs.

Comment: Any idea how I could do this? I would need to override a draw or render method but I can't find anything like this.

Comment: yes you cant, as the the root template of a textbox do not allow a customization to this extent, however your needs can be fulfilled by dynamically adding new textoxes/blocks with different foregrounds, though its a wrong way.