# Underline wrong words in a richtextbox

Tags: c#, winforms, richtextbox, underline

I'm having a lot of trouble on my project and I looked for a solution literally everywhere but I didn't find anything that could help me, or at least I'm so noob that I don't know how to adact the code to my case ( I just started to learn c#). Here's a portion of my code:

```
    private void sottolinea_errori_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string line;
        string[] linea = linea = TextBox_stampa_contenuto.Lines;
        if (TextBox_stampa_contenuto.Text != "")
        {
            foreach (string k in linea)
            {
                string[] parole = k.Split(new Char[] { ' ', ',', '.', ':', '\t' });
                foreach (string s in parole)
                {
                    Regex rgx = new Regex(@"\d");
                    if (!rgx.IsMatch(s))
                    {
                        if (s.Trim() != "")
                        {
                            s.Trim();
                            string path = @"280000parole.txt";
                            bool esito = true;
                            StreamReader file = new StreamReader(path);
                            while ((line = file.ReadLine()) != null && esito == true)
                                if (string.Compare(line, s) == 0)
                                    esito = false;
                            file.Close();
                            if (esito)
                            {
                                //code to underline
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

What it does it's: It checks if every word exists in a txt file that I use as a dictionary. I want to underline the words that don't exist in that txt file. Is there a way to do it?
Thanks!

Comment: You should read that file one time into memory instead of opening and closing it literally for every single word in your input.

Comment: What kind of RichTextBox btw? Winforms, WPF, ASP.net?

Comment: Related question (may be able to get ideas from here): https://stackoverflow.com/q/1926264/3775798