# How can i color each line in a another color?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

```
for (int i = 0; i < newText.Count; i++)
{
    string line = newText[i];
    this.scrollLabel1.ForeColor = string.Format("{0}" ,line[i];
}
```

newText is List
scrollLabel1 is a Label Control.

newText format is like this:

First index 0 line is text
Second index 1 line is date and time
Third index 2 is empty line/space

Then same for the next 3 lines. Text , Date&Time , Empty/space

I want in every 3 lines to color the first line in Red second line in Green.
For example index 0 the text line in Red index 1 the date&tiome line in Green.
And so on for all the lines.

This is how the newText look like:

[image: newText]

Comment: I think you can do this with a `RichTextBox` but not with a label (at least using WinForms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Daniel Kelley mentioned in a comment, you would need to use a [rich text box](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.richtextbox.aspx), which allows a lot of flexibility in terms of customization and formatting.

There's an [answer here on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1926822/1822214) that might be exactly what you're looking for.