# Highlight entire line in Richtextbox if a text is present

Tags: c#, winforms, richtextbox, highlight

[image]

I'm trying to highlight a particular line in my RichTextBox as shown in figure.

```
int ptrsize = 10;
int* linenum; 
for (int i = 0; i < ptrsize; i++)
{           
    int value = (linenum[i]) * 10;
    string searchText = value.ToString();
    int indexToText = richTextBox.Find(searchText);
    int endIndex = searchText.Length;
    richTextBox.Select(indexToText, endIndex);
    richTextBox.SelectionColor = Color.Blue;
}
```

If a text is present (i.e. 2010), i want to highlight the entire line.

2010    19.5    7.37    105    0.67    0.26    0.69

Comment: This could help you: 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1926264/color-different-parts-of-a-richtextbox-string

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will highlight a given line if it contains a given text:

```
void highlightLineContaining(RichTextBox rtb, int line, string search, Color color)
{
    int c0 = rtb.GetFirstCharIndexFromLine(line);
    int c1 = rtb.GetFirstCharIndexFromLine(line+1);
    if (c1 < 0) c1 = rtb.Text.Length;
    rtb.SelectionStart = c0;
    rtb.SelectionLength = c1 - c0;
    if (rtb.SelectedText.Contains(search))
        rtb.SelectionColor = color;
    rtb.SelectionLength = 0;
}
```

You may want to store and restore the original `Selection`.

Sometimes changing the `SelectionBackColor` looks better. Give it a try!

You could call it on the whole RTB :

```
for (int i = 0; i < richTextBox.Lines.Count(); i++)
      highlightLineContaining(richTextBox, i, searchText, Color.Red);
```

Answer (score 1):

I made some changes in previous code with the help of @TaW's code.

[image]

```
for (int j = 0; j < ptrsize; j++)
{
   int value = (linenum[j]) * 10;
   string searchText = value.ToString();
   for (int i = 0; i < richTextBox.Lines.Count(); i++)
      {
         highlightLineContaining(richTextBox, i, searchText, Color.Red);
      }
}
```