# Coloring a specific line of text in richTextBox C#

Tags: c#, listbox, richtextbox

I'm new here and new to C#. I basically wanna color just the maximum temperatures (single line)  in my report, but I've tried all the coding here and nothing works. Can someone please help me? This is my coding, to compare two cities forecast. If there is another easier way to do it with another feature like listBox, please let me know.

If you see the picture, I basically just used an asterisks now to show higher temperature.

Output:

[New output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/46RQV.png)

My code:

```c#
private void getComparison()
{

    this.richTextBox1.Text = ("Start Date:  " + dateTimePicker3.Value.ToString());
    this.richTextBox1.Text = ("COMPARE MULTIPLE CITIES FOR THE WEEK" + Environment.NewLine + "\n\n");

    for (int j = 0; j < 7; j++)
    {
        tempCity1 = Convert.ToInt32(a.getMaxi()[comboBox2.SelectedIndex, j].ToString());
        tempCity2 = Convert.ToInt32(a.getMaxi()[comboBox1.SelectedIndex, j].ToString());

        //City 1
        this.richTextBox1.Text = ("------------------------------------------");
        this.richTextBox1.Text = ("Day:  " + a.getDate(j).ToString());
        this.richTextBox1.Text = ("------------------------------------------");
        this.richTextBox1.Text = ("City:  " + arrCities[comboBox2.SelectedIndex]);
        this.richTextBox1.Text = ("Minimum Temperature:  " + a.getMini()[comboBox2.SelectedIndex, j].ToString() + "°C");
        
        
        
        if (tempCity1 < tempCity2)
        {
            this.richTextBox1.Text =("Maximum Temperature: " + a.getMaxi()[comboBox2.SelectedIndex, j].ToString() + "°C");
            //richTextBox1.SelectionColor = Color.Red;
        }
        else
        {
            this.richTextBox1.Text = ("***Maximum Temperature: " + a.getMaxi()[comboBox2.SelectedIndex, j].ToString() + "°C");
            //richTextBox1.SelectionBackColor = Color.Blue;
        }

        this.richTextBox1.Text = ("Precipitation:  " + a.getPrecip()[comboBox2.SelectedIndex, j].ToString() + "%");
        this.richTextBox1.Text = ("Humidity:  " + a.getHumid()[comboBox2.SelectedIndex, j].ToString() + "%");
        this.richTextBox1.Text = ("Wind speed:  " + a.getWindspeed()[comboBox2.SelectedIndex, j].ToString() + "km / h");
        this.richTextBox1.Text = ("" + Environment.NewLine + "\n\n");

        //City 2
        this.richTextBox1.Text = ("City:  " + arrCities[comboBox1.SelectedIndex]);
        this.richTextBox1.Text = ("Minimum Temperature:  " + a.getMini()[comboBox1.SelectedIndex, j].ToString() + "°C");

        if (tempCity1 > tempCity2)
        {
            this.richTextBox1.Text=("Maximum Temperature: " +  a.getMaxi()[comboBox1.SelectedIndex, j].ToString() + "°C");
            //richTextBox1.SelectionColor = Color.Red;
        }
        else
        {
            this.richTextBox1.Text = ("**Maximum Temperature:" + a.getMaxi()[comboBox1.SelectedIndex, j].ToString() + "°C");
            //richTextBox1.SelectionColor = Color.Blue;
        }


        //("Maximum Temperature:  " + a.getMaxi()[comboBox1.SelectedIndex, j].ToString() + "°C");
        this.richTextBox1.Text = ("Precipitation:  " + a.getPrecip()[comboBox1.SelectedIndex, j].ToString() + "%");
        this.richTextBox1.Text = ("Humidity:  " + a.getHumid()[comboBox1.SelectedIndex, j].ToString() + "%");
        this.richTextBox1.Text = ("Wind speed:  " + a.getWindspeed()[comboBox1.SelectedIndex, j].ToString() + "km / h");

    }
```

Thank you :)

Comment: Maybe this will help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1926264/color-different-parts-of-a-richtextbox-string

Comment: [example1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39085397/highlighting-a-line-in-a-richtextbox1-line-number-a-variable/39085501#39085501) - [example 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28938523/highlight-entire-line-in-richtextbox-if-a-text-is-present/28939964#28939964)

Comment: There is **no way** that code produced that output with a standard RichTextBox.  You have `this.richTextBox1.Text = ` all over the place.  Each of those calls completely replaces the existing text with ONLY the line for that call.  The actual output from the code you've posted would only have the very last "Wind Speed" line, and nothing else.  Additionally, every time you set  the `.Text` property like that, you completely remove any existing formatting (like colors!).  Unless you've got a custom control that inherited from RichTextBox and has an inherited and overidden `.Text` property?

Comment: You're smart :)     Yes like I said if I can do it with a listBox too let me know, the output in the photo is with the listBox but someone told me to do away with the listBox and instead use a richTextBox. My coding is the same with the listBox, just the name richTextbox is replaced. I've tried those links but no success :(

Answer (score 0):

To color items in a listbox, you need to rewrite the "ListBox.DrawItem" event.

Just copy this into your class:

```
private readonly List<Color> colors = new List<Color>();
private readonly List<string> texts = new List<string>();
private void ListBox_Draw(object sender, DrawItemEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Index == -1) return;
    e.DrawBackground();
    Graphics g = e.Graphics;
    //if the item is the maximum temperature item, draw with your color
    g.FillRectangle(new SolidBrush(colors[e.Index]), e.Bounds);
    g.DrawString(texts[e.Index], e.Font, new SolidBrush(e.ForeColor), e.Bounds);
    e.DrawFocusRectangle();
}

private void AddItem(string text, Color color)
{
    colors.Add(color);
    texts.Add(text);
    listBox1.Items.Add("");
}
```

And copy this into the Form_Load function:

```
listBox1.DrawMode = DrawMode.OwnerDrawVariable;//draw items manually
listBox1.DrawItem += ListBox_Draw;//subscribe to draw event
```

How to use it:

Instead of using the listBox1.Items.Add(), you simply use the AddItem(your_text, the_color_of_this_item)

Example:

```
AddItem("Item 1", Color.Red);
AddItem("This is item 2", Color.White);
AddItem("Hello from item 3", Color.Blue);
AddItem("I am item 4", Color.Purple);
AddItem("is it item 5?", Color.Yellow);
AddItem("Im the last item :(", Color.Green);
```

And this is what the example look like:
[image]

Hope this helps!

Comment: So if I then use the method in my loop, how would I write it? Based on the above code? Also will a listBox be easier to use?

Comment: By listbox do you mean instead of writing to richTextBox line-by-line, you want to add items to a listbox for each line? If so, do you also want to color an item in the listbox?

Comment: Yes I already added items to the listBox, like in that output but I just need the coloring part. I wanna color the output in the loop part for maximum tempreture.

Comment: @YumnaDesai I just updated my answer.

Comment: Thank you very much, it works for my normal text (as I selected to show in the photo), but when I call on the array one to get my values to display, it won't work there. How should I implement it there?                                                                      
AddItem("------------------------------------------", Color.Red);
AddItem("City:  ", Color.Blue + arrCities[comboBox2.SelectedIndex]);                    
 PS, I edited my original post with the new photo, cos I couldn't attach it here.

Comment: I cannot see the new photo you posted. All i see is the original one.

Comment: Sorry it shows now :/

Comment: What is the "arrCities"? Are you trying to display the content of arrCities[comboBox2.SelectedIndex]?

If so, try this: 
`AddItem("City: " + arrCities[comboBox2.SelectedIndex], Color.Blue);`

Btw, put this --> ` around the code when you comment :)

Comment: Thank you very much and it finally workssss! Yessss! I am really really grateful for your help, cannot thank you enough - I tried every method but couldn't come right :( . I know I'm a bad coder, I'll remember that next time :D

Comment: @YumnaDesai No problem! Coding is fast to learn, so you'll be good at it in no time. :)

Comment: Hopefully, and be as smart as you :D. Thanks again ::)