# In c# richtextbox how can i highlight words in a sentence sequentially.

Tags: c#

i.e for instance consider this sentence. "This is my sentence." I want the program to display highlighting first 'This' then 'is' and so on. can this actually be done? should i use a timer ? help with brief explanation is greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Well, if your words are delimited by spaces, you can just get the indexes of spaces in your string and move along that list

Comment: Yes, a timer is a good way to do small scale animation in Winforms..Do you know the rules for formatting text in a RTB?

Answer (score 1):

A timer is a good option if you don't want the UI to be blocked all the time. A very basic solution for your problem is the following:

Add this to your initialization code:

```
// index of highlighted text block
var i = 0;    

var timer = new Timer()
{
    Interval = 300
};

timer.Tick += new EventHandler((sender, e) =>
    {
        // split the elements to highlight by space character
        var textElements = this.richTextBox1.Text
            .Split(new char[]{' '}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
            .ToArray();

        // avoid dividing by zero when using modulo operator
        if (textElements.Length > 0)
        {
            // start all over again when the end of text is reached. 
            i = i % textElements.Length;

            // clear the RichTextBox
            this.richTextBox1.Text = string.Empty;

            for (var n = 0; n < textElements.Length; n++)
            {
                // now adding each text block again
                // choose color depending on the index
                this.richTextBox1.AppendText(textElements[n] + ' ', i == n ? Color.Red : Color.Black);
            }

            // increment the index for the next run
            i++;
        }
    });

    timer.Start();
```

This solution uses an extension method. To use this, you must add an extension class like this:

```
static class RichTextBoxExtensions
{
    public static void AppendText(this RichTextBox richtTextBox, string text, Color color)
    {
        richtTextBox.SelectionStart = richtTextBox.TextLength;
        richtTextBox.SelectionLength = 0;

        richtTextBox.SelectionColor = color;
        richtTextBox.AppendText(text);
        richtTextBox.SelectionColor = richtTextBox.ForeColor;
    }
}
```

You can get more information about the extension method I used [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1926264/color-different-parts-of-a-richtextbox-string).

The drawback of this solution is that the RichTextBox is not realy useable while the highlighting is going on. If you want the user to input some text, you should stop the timer first.

Comment: it works but is there a way to trigger this by an event(like button click) and make use of the richtextbox.

Comment: If you change the code and make `timer` a class member or using an anonymous method like I did in the first code, you can easily start/stop the timer from the event handler of your button. While the animation is stopped, the user should be able to use the RichTextBox.