# How to programatically set RichTextbox text and line color?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I'm using [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1926264/color-different-parts-of-a-richtextbox-string/1926822#1926822) to programatically add colored lines to text to my RichTextBox.

My `RichTextBoxExtensions` class is exactly the same as the one in that solution. Then I have an `OutputMessage` class:

```
class OutputMessage
{
    private string _message;
    private Color _color;

    public string Message { get { return _message; } }
    public Color Color { get { return _color; } }

    public OutputMessage(string message, CodeDeployer.enums.OutputTypes ot)
    {
        _message = message;

        switch (ot)
        {
            case enums.OutputTypes.Success:
                _color = Color.Green;
                break;
            case enums.OutputTypes.Error:
                _color= Color.Red;
                break;
            case enums.OutputTypes.Warning:
                _color= Color.DarkOrange; 
                break;
            default:
                _color = Color.Black;
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

On my form, I maintain a `List<OutputMessage>`, then have a method that'll iterate over the `List` and try to put the contents into a `RichTextBox` on my form.

```
private void foo()
{
    this.txtOutput = GetOutput();
    this.txtOutput.Text = GetOutput().Text;
}

private RichTextBox GetOutput()
{
    RichTextBox results = new RichTextBox();

    foreach (OutputMessage om in output)
        results.AppendText(om.Message, om.Color);

    return results;
}
```

If I execute `foo()` with the first line of code, `txtOutput` doesn't change at all. It's just an empty textbox.

If I execute `foo()` with the second line of code, `txtOutput` *does* have all of the text from my `List<OutputMessage>`, however the color is lost.

If I change `GetOutput` to directly interact with the control on the form, it works as expected. Having it accept a `RichTextBox` as an argument works as well.

Can someone explain this to me? I'm guessing it has something to do with how things are passed by reference / by value, but I don't understand.

Comment: You are using a windows forms or wpf control and not an asp.net web control, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`.Text`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.richtextbox.text.aspx) property of `RichTextBox` is plain unformatted text.

> The Text property does not return any information about the formatting applied to the contents of the RichTextBox. To get the rich text formatting (RTF) codes, use the Rtf property.

So you should try using the [`.Rtf`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.richtextbox.rtf.aspx) property instead:

```
this.txtOutput.Rtf = GetOutput().Rtf;
```