# Display all characters of a text file using RichTextBox Control

Tags: c#, .net, special-characters, richtextbox

I would like to read text file and display in **RichTextBox control**   and display all possible characters including **ESC FF SO SI** and **empty spaces**.

I am not sure how to do it like this.

[image]

This code doesnt help...

```
if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK) {
    string text = File.ReadAllText(openFileDialog1.FileName);
    richTextBox1.Text = text;
}
```

Any clue?

Comment: What do you mean by "displaying" the special characters? How exactly would you like to print an **ESC**-character? As the string "ESC"?. You could iterate over the whole ASCII keycodes from 0 to 255, print the printable characters, and substitute the control-characters with another string. Refer to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Control_character for these.

Comment: @MaximilianGerhardt Please take a look at the image I just added.

Comment: Make sure that you use the same encoding in both the editor to see the contents (where "ESC", "FF", etc. are shown) and to read the file (one of the overloads of ReadAllText takes the encoding as an argument). By using the same encoding, you should see the same things.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One way to do this would be to generate a richtext yourself by iterating through all the characters in your loaded file, but if you find a special sequence character, substitute it with a bold / unterlined / italic name of the sequence. Take a look at http://sourceforge.net/projects/netrtfwriter/ on how to create RTF documents with these formatting options yourself, which you can then give the `richTextBox`.

EDIT: Okay, an RTF writer may be overkill for that task. The RTFBox has **very** limited possibilites, but it's okay for this one. Take a look at this file. 
[image: hex]

This contains all the ASCII characters from 0 to 127. Here's how my application prints them:

[image: ap]

The code is simple. I use a dictionary to substitue the special characters, and I use an extension from [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1926264/color-different-parts-of-a-richtextbox-string) to get some color in it. If you want fancier coloring and formating (like smooth, rounded edges around your words), don't use `RichTextBox`, but something more advanced. This should get you started.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Drawing;
using System.IO;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace FileViewer
{
    public partial class FileViewerForm : Form
    {
        public FileViewerForm()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        //Click handler.
        private void btnLoad_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //Ask them to select a file.
            openFileDialog.Title = "Please select a file";
            openFileDialog.Filter = "Any file|*.*";
            var dlgResult = openFileDialog.ShowDialog();
            if (dlgResult != DialogResult.OK)
                return;
            richTextBox1.Clear();

            //Get the text as a char array.
            char[] text = File.ReadAllText(openFileDialog.FileName).ToCharArray();

            //loop through all of them
            for (int i = 0; i < text.Length; i++)
            {
                //is this a special ASCII character?
                if (lSpecialDict.ContainsKey(text[i]))
                {
                    string replacement;
                    //get the replacement
                    lSpecialDict.TryGetValue(text[i], out replacement);
                    if (replacement != null)
                        //Print it out with DarkGray as backcolor, Firebrick as font color.
                        richTextBox1.AppendText("[" + replacement + "]", Color.LightGray, Color.Firebrick);
                }
                //just a normal character? Then append it.
                else
                    richTextBox1.AppendText(text[i].ToString());
            }
        }

        //Contains the substition strings for the characters. A char --> string mapping.
        private Dictionary<char, string> lSpecialDict 
            = new Dictionary<char, string>()
        {
            { '\0',      "NUL" }, {(char)0x01, "SOH" }, {(char)0x02, "STX" },
            {(char)0x03, "ETX" }, {(char)0x04, "EOT" }, {(char)0x05, "ENQ" },
            {(char)0x06, "ACK" }, {(char)0x07, "BEL" }, {(char)0x08, "BS"  },
            {(char)0x09, "HT"  }, {(char)0x0A, "LF"  }, {(char)0x0B, "VT"  },
            {(char)0x0C, "FF"  }, {(char)0x0D, "CR"  }, {(char)0x0E, "SO"  },
            {(char)0x0F, "SI"  }, {(char)0x10, "DLE" }, {(char)0x11, "DC1" },
            {(char)0x12, "DC2" }, {(char)0x13, "DC3" }, {(char)0x14, "DC4" },
            {(char)0x15, "NAK" }, {(char)0x16, "SYN" }, {(char)0x17, "ETB" },
            {(char)0x18, "CAN" }, {(char)0x19, "EM"  }, {(char)0x1A, "SUB" },
            {(char)0x1B, "ESC" }, {(char)0x1C, "FS"  }, {(char)0x1D, "GS"  },
            {(char)0x1E, "RS"  }, {(char)0x1F, "US"  }, {(char)0x7F, "DEL" },
        };

        private void FileViewerForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
    public static class RichTextBoxExtensions
    {
        public static void AppendText(this RichTextBox box, string text, System.Drawing.Color bgcolor, Color fontcolor)
        {
            box.SelectionStart = box.TextLength;
            box.SelectionLength = 0;

            var saved = box.SelectionBackColor;
            var saved2 = box.SelectionColor;
            box.SelectionBackColor = bgcolor;
            box.SelectionColor = fontcolor;
            box.AppendText(text);
            box.SelectionBackColor = saved;
            box.SelectionColor = saved2;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Sounds great... Would you mind to provide any simple example so the ESC FF or SI characters is gonna be like at the shown image, please?