# Visual C# - Changing text color of specific cell on a specific row

Tags: datagridview

I've spent my limit of a week on this, and now I'm getting a little frustrated.  I'm trying, to no avail, to be able to change the colors of a specific datagridview cell, based on whether the same cell in the row before it was a different value.  It is a compare datagridview, so I want to highlight when record 1 field x is different from record 2 field x.  The datagridview is built through some heavy lifting, and once it's built I'd like to loop through all cells and highlight the ones that are not equal between the 2 records (but not the entire row, just the cell in both records).

So, my datagridview might look like this:

```
field 1    field 2     field3     field4     field5
value1     value2      value3     value4     value5
value1     value2      value8     value7     value5
```

In this case, I want to highlight the cells in field 3 as red, and the cells in field 4 as red because the 2 values are different.  There will only ever be 2 records in this datagridview table because it's intended to show 2 full records side by side for comparison.  I can copy some code in here if needed, but I'm pretty sure I've tried every method except for the right method.  They could certainly improve the coloring methods of the datagridview and make it a little more straightforward.  Anyone have any ideas?  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For completeness, setting the color as [Simo suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35734226/3773066), you can do this in the [`CellFormatting`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.cellformatting(v=vs.110).aspx) method. From the link:

> The CellFormatting event occurs every time each cell is painted, so you should avoid lengthy processing when handling this event. This event also occurs when the cell FormattedValue is retrieved or its GetFormattedValue method is called.

Essentially, the following solution will set the `ForeColor` for the cells of the formatting column whenever a cell in that column repaints - which occurs when values change, mouse over/click/etc, form or cell gains focus or is highlighted, ET AL. Since you'll only ever have two rows, it makes things simple:

```cs
this.dataGridView1.CellFormatting += DataGridView1_CellFormatting;

private void DataGridView1_CellFormatting(object sender, DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs e)
{
    if (this.dataGridView1[e.ColumnIndex, 0].Value.ToString() != this.dataGridView1[e.ColumnIndex, 1].Value.ToString())
    {
        this.dataGridView1[e.ColumnIndex, 0].Style.ForeColor = Color.Red;
        this.dataGridView1[e.ColumnIndex, 1].Style.ForeColor = Color.Red;
    }
    else /*See Note */
    {
        this.dataGridView1[e.ColumnIndex, 0].Style.ForeColor = Color.Black;
        this.dataGridView1[e.ColumnIndex, 1].Style.ForeColor = Color.Black;
    }
}
```

*Note*: If you are able to edit the cell values, consider the `else-statement` I've added in - changing the value of a column's cells to match when previously they differed will leave the text colored red without the additional code.

Comment: Well, all I can say is thanks.  This is the first time something has worked for me, but I cannot understand the code behind it.  I guess that first line triggers the the cellformatting routine to be triggered for every cell with a value?  I'm going to pick apart that function at a later time.  For now, thanks!  I'm just glad it's working somehow....Finally!

Comment: @user1420914 I added a link, quote, and minor description to clarify the `CellFormatting` event. But in answer, yes, the first line adds your method handler to the `CellFormatting` event. Usually you'll see this kind of code in the `Form.Designer.cs` class because hooking up events from the designer will drop the code there - but you can also add that line in the constructor if you like.

Comment: Thanks again.  I wish I would have asked the question a week ago!  I still think there should be a way to read through all of the columns in the table and compare line for line while marking them red after the table has been built, but I digress.....Seems like that would be a more efficient approach when there are thousands of records in the table.

Comment: You should be able to do that **a)** right after manually adding data is finished or **b)** in the `DataGridView.DataBindingComplete` event for a bound `DataSource`. Though, I'm not sure how the efficiency would compare honestly. Even for thousands of records, the `CellFormatting` event is only called on cells being re-painted - which, unless you have a monster-sized screen and `DataGridView`, should be minimal. And since the code is also minimal, its impact is negligible - `CellFormatting` will be called just as often regardless if you add a handler or not.

Comment: @OhBeWise would be it be possible to change the font color of a specific text/character only? Ex: I want to change the font styling for numbers in a record but keep the words the default style.

Comment: @NuWin It's more involved. To get multiple colors of text within the same box, you'd need to use a [`RichTextBox`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.richtextbox(v=vs.110).aspx). You could house this in your own [custom `DataGridView` column](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180996.aspx), for example [like this](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/31823/RichTextBox-Cell-in-a-DataGridView). To set the text with multiple colors, follow [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1926264/3773066).

Answer (score 1):

Something like...

```
dataGridView1.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[columnIndex].Style.ForeColor = Color.Red;
```

...?

Comment: I wish it was as easy as that (it should be).  I'm not sure if I need to do some sort of refresh or something, or put it in a different position.  I've tried this line in several spots.  It seems like I had it setting a color at one time in some weird place, but is wasn't practical where it was at.