# Can make the color separately?

Tags: c#, winforms, user-interface

[image]

As you can see it is all red. I need the number to be red, but text to be black as shown on picture below. This is my code :

[image]

```
private void listBox2_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    str1 = str;
    str1 += listBox2.Text;
    wassaw.Text = str1;
    TextBox1.ForeColor = Color.Red;
    switch (str1)
    {
        case "Привет1" :
            TextBox1.Text = "" + Environment.NewLine + "1. привет " + Environment.NewLine + "2. привет  " + Environment.NewLine + "3. привет  ";
            break;
        case "Привет2" :
            TextBox1.Text = "" + Environment.NewLine + "1. привет  ";
            break;
        case "Приветф3" :
            TextBox1.Text = "" + Environment.NewLine + "1  привет  ";
            break;
        case "Приветы4" :
            TextBox1.Text = "" + Environment.NewLine + "1  привет  ";
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Use `DataGridView` instead of `TextBox`

Comment: You can use an owner-drawn listbox or listview

Comment: Уважаемые, пожалуйста, ознакомиться с проектами, пусть под правильный цвет поможет.в http://c2n.меня/3yr0H5D

Answer (score 1):

Not using a regular `TextBox`. The `TextBox` control just allows single color, single formatting text.

There are several options. You could create your own control, use external libraries, or you can use the `RichTextBox` which does allow formatting and coloring. With a little help, you can achieve what you want:

See this question how to do that: [Color different parts of a RichTextBox string](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1926264/993547).

Another option would be to use a grid control, like the `TableLayoutPanel` and put the numbers and text in separate labels.

Comment: Уважаемые, пожалуйста, ознакомиться с проектами, пусть под правильный цвет поможет.в http://c2n.меня/3yr0H5D