# How can i highlight and color specific text in richTextBox?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I tried first this. Right after adding the text from a listView to the richTextBox.

```
void lvnf_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (ListViewCostumControl.lvnf.SelectedItems.Count > 0)
            {
                richTextBox1.Text = File.ReadAllText(ListViewCostumControl.lvnf.Items[ListViewCostumControl.lvnf.SelectedIndices[0]].Text);
                int length = richTextBox1.TextLength;
                richTextBox1.SelectionStart = length;
                richTextBox1.SelectionLength = richTextBox1.Text.Length;
                richTextBox1.SelectionColor = Color.Red;               
            }
        }
```

In this case i thought it will color all the text in richTextBox in red but i didn't the text in richTextBox still black as original.

But what i want to do is after the line:

```
richTextBox1.Text = File.ReadAllText(ListViewCostumControl.lvnf.Items[ListViewCostumControl.lvnf.SelectedIndices[0]].Text);
```

To color in Red all the places in richTextBox that the text/string "Form1" is exist.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1926264/color-different-parts-of-a-richtextbox-string

Comment: Use the debugger to see the problem. Read about string methods, kije indexOf to see how to find specific text

Comment: If your goal is changing color of all text, you can simply set `ForeColor` to `Color.Red`. Also your code will work as expected if you make a correction: `richTextBox1.SelectionStart = 0;`

Answer (score 0):

If you are Replacing the whole Text available in the `richTextBox1` with the new Text that are supplied by the File. then the `SelectionStart` will be from `0` and the `SelectionLength` will be the length of the input string; ie.,

```
string fileContent = File.ReadAllText(ListViewCostumControl.lvnf.Items[ListViewCostumControl.lvnf.SelectedIndices[0]].Text);
int length = fileContent.Length;
richTextBox1.Text = fileContent;
richTextBox1.SelectionStart = 0;
richTextBox1.SelectionLength = length;
richTextBox1.SelectionColor = Color.Red;
```

If you are Appending the file Content to the Existing Text then you can do like the following:

```
int startIndex= richTextBox1.TextLength;
richTextBox1.AppendText(fileContent);
richTextBox1.SelectionStart = startIndex;
richTextBox1.SelectionLength = length;
richTextBox1.SelectionColor = Color.Red;
```

Which means you have to set the selection start as the current TextContent Length. then Append the content and then set SelectionLength as length of the content