# Color different texts of a RichTextBox string in C#

Tags: c#, richtextbox

I want to coloured different parts of a richtextbox with different colors, same as posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1926264/color-different-parts-of-a-richtextbox-string).

But with one difference, in my case I need to use the method Insert of the richtextbox to insert message at the top.

I was using classical method:

myRichTextBox.Text.Insert(0, myMessage);

but using it I cannot coloured different parts of the message so I have done below extension methods:

```
public static class RichTextBoxExtensions
{
    public static string Insert(this string str, int index, RichTextBox box, string text, Color color)
    {
        box.SelectionStart = box.TextLength;
        box.SelectionLength = 0;

        box.SelectionColor = color;
        //box.Text = str.Insert(0, box, text, color);
        box.Text = str.Insert(index, text);
        box.SelectionColor = box.ForeColor;

        return box.Text;
    }
}
```

and then I use it by calling in the following way from any point of my program:

```
    private void PrintMessage(RichTextBox box, string message, Color color)
    {
        box.Text = box.Text.Insert(0, box, message, color);
    }
```

But it is not working, it throws an exception in extension method Insert in line:

```
box.Text = str.Insert(0, box, text, color);
```

It says "Stack overflow". Any ideas?

**UPDATED**:

```
    private void PrintMessage(RichTextBox box, string message, Color color)
    {
        box.SelectedText = box.SelectedText.Insert(0, box, message, color);
    }

public static class RichTextBoxExtensions
{
    public static string Insert(this string str, int index, RichTextBox box, string text, Color color)
    {
        box.SelectionStart = box.TextLength;
        box.SelectionLength = 0;

        box.SelectionColor = color;
        box.SelectedText = str.Insert(index, text);
        box.SelectionColor = box.ForeColor;

        return box.Text;
    }
}
```

But it does not work, text does not appear coloured.

**NOTE**:

I need text to be added at the top of the richtextbox control, not at the bottom, so I was using Insert instead of AppendText.

**UPDATE 2**:
Using AppendText and setting SelectionStart to 0 to append text at the top of the richtextbox as TaW says [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38097850/richtextbox-prepend-new-text-with-color), fails the first time you print a message into the richtextbox. Rest of time (not the first) is going ok.

So how to make it work also for the first string appended into the richtextbox?

```
    public static void AppendText(this RichTextBox rtb, string text, Color color)
    {            
        rtb.SelectionStart = 0;            // set the cursor to the target position
        rtb.SelectionLength = 0;           // nothing selected, yet
        rtb.SelectedText = text;           // this inserts the new text 
        rtb.SelectionLength = text.Length; // now we prepare the new formatting
        rtb.SelectionColor = color;
    }
```

Comment: You've got a circular reference, your `Insert` method calls itself from inside itself.

Comment: `string` doesn't know squat about rich text, so your extension should probably go against a RichTextBox control, not a string variable, like in the linked article.  Use SelectedText versus Text.  The Text property ignores the rich text attributes.

Comment: @Equalsk Yes, you are right. I have correct by replacing it by box.Text = str.Insert(index, text); See edited post. But now the problem is that is not coloured.

Comment: [Color different parts of a RichTextBox string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1926264/color-different-parts-of-a-richtextbox-string)

Comment: Other issues aside: _I was using classical method: myRichTextBox.Text.Insert(0, myMessage);_ The really classical method is `richTextBox1.SelectionStart = 0;
richTextBox1.SelectionLength = 0;
richTextBox1.SelectedText = myMessage` - __Never touch the Text property__ or you will mess up previous formatting.

Comment: @Equalsk in the link you provided (that is the same I provided) is adding text at the end (bottom) of the richtextbox, not at the top as I want.

Comment: Good catch. I had not explicitly written out the code in the post; you need to set the SelectionStart back to `s` or `0` in your case before setting the length.. Corrected and tested.

Answer (score 1):

To Add text at the top with color change, I used this code, for me it is the best solution.
It does not use copy/paste or text deletion and rewriting.

```
 public void Log(RichTextBox myTextBox, string Testo, Color colore)
    {
            myTextBox.SelectionStart = 0;
            myTextBox.SelectionLength = 0;
            myTextBox.SelectionColor= colore;
            myTextBox.SelectedText = Testo;
    }
```

Answer (score -2):

You wrote the prototype wrong and implementation is not right. I made a working code. All you need is to add a Richtextbox element in your Form and name it box.

```
    using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;
namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
public static class RichTextBoxExtensions
{
    public static void AppendText(this RichTextBox box, string text, Color color)
    {
        box.SelectionStart = box.TextLength;
        box.SelectionLength = 0;

        box.SelectionColor = color;
        box.AppendText(text);
        box.SelectionColor = box.ForeColor;
    }
}
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        box.AppendText("[" + DateTime.Now.ToShortTimeString() + "]", Color.Red);
        box.AppendText(" ");
        box.AppendText("GREEN TEXT", Color.Green);
        box.AppendText(": ");
        box.AppendText("BLUE TEXT", Color.Blue);
        box.AppendText(Environment.NewLine);
    }
}
}
```

To call it in your code, make it like this

```
private void PrintMessage(RichTextBox box, string message, Color color)
 {
     box.Text = box.AppendText(message, color);
 }
```

[image]

Code taken from [Richtextbox prepend new text with color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38097850/richtextbox-prepend-new-text-with-color)

UPDATE::
To write on top of Richtextbox used this modified code (i did a dirty fix using clipboard) but it works

```
        public static void AppendTextToTop(this RichTextBox box, string text, Color color)
    {
        Clipboard.Clear();
        box.SelectAll();
        box.Copy();
        box.Clear();
        box.SelectionStart = box.TextLength;
        box.SelectionLength = 0;

        box.SelectionColor = color;
        box.AppendText(text);
        box.SelectionColor = box.ForeColor;

        box.Paste();
    }
```

Comment: Looks like you copied the code from the linked article.  Please attribute.

Comment: But AppendText, appends text at the bottom of the richtextbox, not at the top. I want text to be added to richtextbox at the top each time I add it.

Comment: An unfortunate names and also wrong code. Look into the the original post or my comment above!

Comment: I added a quick fix for your problem

Comment: TaW what is your problem ?

Comment: @TaW ok, I had a look at your example in the link posted at the beginning of my post, but your solution posted there fails the first time you print a message into the richtextbox. Rest of times, it is working but the first one not, that is, the first time message is printed in black, not with the desired color. So how to solve this? See my last UPDATE 2.