# Color Rich TextBox C# windows forms

Tags: c#, multithreading, winforms, richtextbox

I have a multithreaded application , the `richtextbox` is updated from another `thread` than the one it's created on : `Form1`
So I used a delegate trick to do so :

```
delegate void SetTextCallback(string text);
    public static void SetText(String text)
    {
        if (Form1.myform.richtextbox.InvokeRequired)
        {
            SetTextCallback d = new SetTextCallback(SetText);
            Form1.myform.richtextbox.Invoke(d, new object[] { text });
        }
        else
        {
            Form1.myform.richtextbox.AppendText(text);
        }
    }
```

**PROBLEM** : how can I color this `text` ?

Comment: Related : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1926264/color-different-parts-of-a-richtextbox-string

Comment: It's not access thread on UI. I recommand to you [BackgroundWorker](https://www.google.co.kr/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0ahUKEwiRtvrHzfzNAhUKo5QKHZMwA-UQFggdMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fko-kr%2Flibrary%2Fsystem.componentmodel.backgroundworker(v%3Dvs.110).aspx&usg=AFQjCNFJtxBEXFskuuWh3S2O519ID2tErg&sig2=OjcX_fvKi2VqUUO1GxPPSg&bvm=bv.127178174,d.dGo)!

Comment: Same as you would from a non threaded app.

Comment: @Mr.MK : What are you talking about?? What is wrong with using a thread if he performs invocation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use the [Select Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xc4fh98s(v=vs.110).aspx) on the RichTextBox after you append your text to select it (use TextLenght to find the range to select). Then you could use [SelectionColor Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.richtextbox.selectioncolor(v=vs.110).aspx) to change the color.

Of course this should be done on the UI thread.

```
public void SetText(string text, Color color)
{
    if (this.RichTextBox1.InvokeRequired) {
        SetTextCallBack d = new SetTextCallBack(SetText);
        this.Invoke(d, {
            text,
            color
        });
    } else {
        int length = this.RichTextBox1.TextLength;
        this.RichTextBox1.AppendText(text);
        this.RichTextBox1.Select(length, text.Length);
        this.RichTextBox1.SelectionColor = color;
    }
}
```

I have use these dummy task to test it.

```
private void StartServer
{
    Task y = new Task(() => this.SetText("Yellow Text", Color.Yellow));
    Task z = new Task(() => this.SetText("Red Text", Color.Red));
    y.Start();
    z.Start();
}
```

Comment: If thread access to ui, maybe need [lock](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ko-kr/us-en/library/c5kehkcz.aspx) keyword!

Comment: Yes I need to do it just after that . And Iam not that good , that's why i asked here

Comment: Nope, the if InvokeRequired Then Invoke should do the trick. The code in the else clause will always be executed on the UI thread. I don't see the need for a lock here. Of course the color value should be send with the text in your delegate param.

Comment: @MarcoGuignard And what about the code in the if statement ? will that take the color in consideration

Comment: @Mr.MK : When calling `Invoke()` you **move the execution to the UI thread**. So this will always execute on the UI, no locks required. If `InvokeRequired` returns `False` then the code **is already running on the UI thread** (or the control is not visible).

Comment: @Mr.MK : I suggest you read a little more about how [**Thread-safe calls work**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171728(v=vs.110).aspx).