# C# Formatted Text as a variable

Tags: c#, winforms

A few years ago I was working on a project that wrote formatted text (color, styling, etc) to a RichTextBox. I remember finding a solution online where you could have all of this formatting stored inside of a variable so that you could set it directly to the RichTextBox. Unfortunately, I don't have that code anymore, nor can I find the solution.

Essentially, there was a main class that acted like a `StringBuilder`, only you could add `Span` objects to it which each could have their own defined styling, so one span could be green and another blue. Then, when the formatted string was built it could be sent directly to a control.

Does anyone know of the classes/library I'm talking about? I would much prefer to do it this way as opposed to having to programmatically select the text and change the color after it is written.

Comment: You will probably find [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1926264/color-different-parts-of-a-richtextbox-string) relevant to your needs.

Comment: It sounds as if you have built Rtf text. You can build it and then replace the rtb.Rtf with it. 'Span' otoh sounds like html?