# How to change the foreground color for parts of a dynamically built property using MVVM pattern

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

I have a String property that acts as a Path for a file.

The String is built and values are appended to it as an Observable Collection is populated.

The Observable Collection is built with Student objects and the String I am building references a Name property for the Student. Each Student's Name is separated by a | that does not need coloring, it should stay black.

So, for example, the String should look like this after I added three Students to the Collection:

```
[associatedColorForFirstStudent]firstStudentName | [associatedColorForSecondStudent]secondStudentName | [associatedColorForThirdStudent]thirdStudentName
```

Note: all the pipes are black and not any Student's associated color.

Right now, I am setting the String's entire foreground to the associated Brush for the last Student added to the Collection.

So, my String looks like

```
[thirdStudentsColor]firstStudentName | secondStudentName | thirdStudentName
```

I tried a few things with the `<Run>` tag but it didn't seem to work, it made the entire String just black.

```
<dxe:TextEdit Style="{StaticResource StudentFullPath}" Text="{Binding FullStudentPathText, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" 
                              Foreground="{Binding AssociatedStudentBrush, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
```

In my View Model, I am setting the StudentFullPath Property with this method:

```
private string ConfigureStudentFullPath(ObservableCollection<Student>Students)
{
    string path = "";
    foreach (Student s in Students)
    {
        path += "[" + s.Name + "]";
    } 
    return path;
}
```

Note: AssociatedStudentBrush is a property that references a Brush property of a Student. It is set when a single Student is added.

EDIT: the duplicates do not work for me because I am trying to adhere to the MVVM design pattern as close as possible.

Comment: What type of control is your observablecollection bound to?

Comment: ItemsControl, sorry, will edit.

Comment: Are you trying to change the displayed color of the String property, the observablecollection, or both?

Comment: Sorry, just the String.

Comment: Alright, what control are you binding the string to then?

Comment: The TextEdit control that I posted is the control that will host the String. That is my attempt for now.

Comment: I would recommend using a `richtextbox` instead if you want to manipulate the text in such a way.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Color different parts of a RichTextBox string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1926264/color-different-parts-of-a-richtextbox-string)

Comment: If the link I posted as a duplicate doesn't quite solve your issue, feel free to edit this question or ask another specifying what the problem is, but richtextbox should be what you're looking for.

Comment: Is there no way to this in a more MVVM fashion or strictly through XAML?

Comment: If you bind to the textchanged or selectionchanged events using an event trigger, and then bind to the other properties (like SelectionBrush), then perhaps you can call code in your view model to append text one piece of the string at a time (in a for loop for example) where the events will get fired off each time. This would allow your viewmodel to change the properties without knowing anything about the view (mvvm). There are various other ways as well that I can't fit into a couple comments. Give it a try on your own and if you need additional help, I'd ask it as a separate question.

Comment: I'm fairly sure this can be done cleanly with MVVM.  Give me a few minutes to make an example.

Comment: Does the end result need to be a directly editable TextBox, or would a TextBlock be acceptable?

Comment: TextBlock should be fine, I believe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This the best I was able to do in the time I had available (updated to show a border).

View-Models:

```
class MainWindowVm
{
    public MainWindowVm()
    {
        PathParts = new ObservableCollection<PathPart>();
        Path = new ObservableCollection<StudentData>();

        var allStudents = new ObservableCollection<StudentData>(new[]
                                                 {
                                                     new StudentData() { Name = "Bob", TextColor = Colors.Aqua },
                                                     new StudentData() { Name = "Mary", TextColor = Colors.Red },
                                                     new StudentData() { Name = "Joe", TextColor = Colors.Blue },
                                                     new StudentData() { Name = "Dan", TextColor = Colors.Green },
                                                 });

        Path.CollectionChanged += (sender, e) => { UpdatePath(); };

        //This should would normally be part of a button command, or something else that triggers a change to the path.
        Path.Add(allStudents[1]);
        Path.Add(allStudents[2]);
        Path.Add(allStudents[0]);
    }

    private void UpdatePath()
    {
        PathParts.Clear();
        foreach (var student in Path)
        {
            PathParts.Add(new PathPart() { Text = student.Name, Color = student.TextColor });
            if (student != Path.Last())
            {
                PathParts.Add(new PathPart() { Text = " | ", Color = Colors.Black });
            }
        }
    }

    public ObservableCollection<PathPart> PathParts { get; }
    public ObservableCollection<StudentData> Path { get; }
}

class PathPart
{
    public string Text { get; set; }
    public Color Color { get; set; }
}

class StudentData
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Color TextColor { get; set; }
}
```

XAML:

```
<Window
    x:Class="WpfApp2.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp2"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    Title="MainWindow"
    Width="800"
    Height="450"
    mc:Ignorable="d">
    <Window.DataContext>
        <local:MainWindowVm />
    </Window.DataContext>
    <Border
        Margin="8"
        Padding="3"
        HorizontalAlignment="Left"
        VerticalAlignment="Top"
        BorderBrush="Black"
        BorderThickness="1">
        <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Path=PathParts}">
            <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" />
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Text}">
                        <TextBlock.Foreground>
                            <SolidColorBrush Color="{Binding Path=Color}" />
                        </TextBlock.Foreground>
                    </TextBlock>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        </ItemsControl>
    </Border>
</Window>
```

I didn't have time to make everything implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`, but everything *should* flow correctly.

It gives me this result:

[image: Result]

Comment: Very nice, thank you. Question, though, Is it possible to have this enclosed in a single border, like a box, to give the impression that is a single TextBlock?

Comment: Very easy, just wrap the `ItemsControl` in a `Border` element, and specify a `BorderBrush`, and `BorderThickness`. Give the `Border` some `Padding` to keep it from bunching right up against the text, and you should be god to go.  I'll update the example.