# Write to the left and right side of textview

Tags: c#, styling, text-alignment

I want to be able to write to both the left and right side of a textfield, depending on if the message is sent from the user or the server.

So far I have this:

```
if (Equals(first, Name))// checks if im the one sending message 
{
    BeginInvokeOnMainThread(delegate
    {                            
        OutgoingText.Text += StateObject.Response + "\n";
        OutgoingText.TextAlignment = UITextAlignment.Left;
    });
}
else
{
    BeginInvokeOnMainThread(delegate
    {
        OutgoingText.Text += StateObject.Response + "\n";
        OutgoingText.TextAlignment = UITextAlignment.Right;
    });
}
```

Unfortunately `Alignment.Right` and `Alignment.Left` move the entire contents of the text field over. I imagine there are many solutions to this problem, but I am just beginning so the more simple, the better.

Comment: What do you mean by "both left and right side of a text field?"  What is the type of the OutgoingText object?  Perhaps you just need two fields, a left and a right, where one or both can be empty?

Answer (score 0):

Adapted from here: [Color different parts of a RichTextBox string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1926264/color-different-parts-of-a-richtextbox-string)

You can extend the Richtextbox class and create a method that accepts an alignment parameter. It could look something like this:

```
public static class RichTextBoxExtensions
{
    public static void AppendText(this RichTextBox box, string text, HorizontalAlignment align)
    {
        box.SelectionStart = box.TextLength;
        box.SelectionLength = 0;

        box.SelectionAlignment = align;
        box.AppendText(text);
    }
}
```

You would use this like this:

```
richTextBox1.AppendText("lasdflaksjdflakjsdf\n", HorizontalAlignment.Left);
richTextBox1.AppendText("lasdflaksjdflakjsdf\n", HorizontalAlignment.Right);
```