# How do I set the text inside a comment to the color of the comment?

Tags: c#, winforms, richtextbox, syntax-highlighting

How do I set the color of text inside of a comment to the color of the 
comment? 
 
The problem is that only "/" and "-" work as comments, but nothing else.

Note: I'm using a rich textbox for syntax highlighting. 
I use [Patrik's project](https://www.codeproject.com/articles/10675/enabling-syntax-highlighting-in-a-richtextbox?fid=190210&df=90&mpp=25&sort=Position&view=Normal&spc=Relaxed&fr=76&prof=True) on Codeproject.

This is what I use to enable comments inside the rich textbox.

```C#
M_syntaxRichTextBox.Settings.CommentColor = Color.Green;

M_syntaxRichTextBox.Settings.EnableComments = true;
```

Comment: Is this WinForms, WPF, ASP.NET ? how are the comments generated ? how come each comment has a certain color ?

Comment: It's WinForms. Most text editors do this to where they set specific keywords, strings, and comments to different color in one set.

Comment: This is not the standard RTB. Looks like you are using code from Patrik's article from CodeProject. Perhaps take a look at his code or at least put a link here to the original article.

Comment: @danish What is the standard RTB?

Comment: This might help you..
Check this thread... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1926264/color-different-parts-of-a-richtextbox-string?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa

Comment: @TrueGDVIC3 RichTextBox. The one that comes with the framework

Comment: @danish So, would I have to change my code completely to make it agree with the framework or would I have to add a few things?

Comment: @TrueGDVIC3 I don't know.You do not need to revert back to standard control. The author has already extended it. I have not read the the original source code. Nor does the author appears to be active on CP anymore. It surely works based on the screenshots in the article. So, as I said, you might need to revisit the article and the article code.