# Can I use this old snippet of code to change the text color of one line in a Rich Text Box?

Tags: c#, richtextbox

With no errors present, the color of the text in a RichTextBox field isn't changing.

This is for a simple text based game in c# (which I'm very new to). I've tried a multitude of different solutions online to no avail. I found this old code from 2006 which appears to go in without errors but doesn't seem to change anything. My assumption where the breakdown is happening is that the text isn't actually being selected, though the syntax appears to be correct. I've tried inserting some debug code in the form of reading the length of text, and it gives the correct number - in this example, the selection length shows as 26 which is correct.

```
void AppendText(RichTextBox box, Color color, string text)
    {
        int start = box.TextLength;
        box.AppendText(text);
        int end = box.TextLength;

        //Textbox may transform chars, so (end-start) != text.Length
        box.Select(start, end - start);
        {
            box.SelectionColor = color;
        }
        box.SelectionLength = 0;
        box.Text += Environment.NewLine;
    }

//which is being called by:

AppendText(rtbMessages, Color.Red, "Yarr Matey, this be a test");
```

I expected it to change this text to Red. It doesn't change the text color.

Interestingly, if (instead of box.SelectionColor) you insert box.Forecolor, it does update the entire text box to red - leading me to believe that the selection part is the broken link.

There are no errors present when running this code.

Comment: Why not use this snippet from 2018 instead: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1926264/color-different-parts-of-a-richtextbox-string

Comment: `box.Text += Environment.NewLine;`  Don't do this.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Color different parts of a RichTextBox string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1926264/color-different-parts-of-a-richtextbox-string)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I read that using `+=` to append text resets all the applied colors, so whatever success your earlier parts of your code may achieve, they might well be wiped out by the last line!

I linked a related SO question in the comments; it seems broadly similar to yours but 225+ people seem to appreciate that it works. It's an extension method so you need to declare it in a static class, but it then neatly becomes available on any RichTextBox you have..

---

EDIT: So you said it works but you're not looking forward to changing all your code

I'm guessing your code looks like this:

```
AppendText(rtbMessages, Color.Red, "Yarr Matey, this be a test");
AppendText(rtbMessages2, Color.Blue, "Yarr Matey, this be a test 2");
AppendText(rtbMessages3, Color.Green, "Yarr Matey, this be a test 3");
```

Either change your AppendText method (that they're all calling) so it calls the extension:

```
public static class RichTextBoxExtensions
{
  //this is THE EXTENSION method
  public static void AppendText(this RichTextBox box, string text, Color color)
  {
    ...
  }
}


//this is YOUR code
void AppendText(RichTextBox box, Color color, string text)
{
    //call THE EXTENSION code
    box.AppendText(color, text);
}

//now your code, calls your code, calls the extension
AppendText(rtbMessages, Color.Red, "Yarr Matey, this be a test");
```

Or run a find replace in your code:

```
FIND: AppendText\((\w+), (.*)
REPL: $1.AppendText($2)


AppendText(rtbMessages, Color.Red, "Yarr Matey, this be a test");
           ^^^^^^^^^^^  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
               $1                        $2
```

It will transform all your code:

```
FROM: AppendText(rtb1, color, text);
TO:   rtb1.AppendText(color, text);
```

Comment: Caius Jard, thanks a ton for the help! This took some setup (I'm quite green!) but I've got it working in a test environment.

Can't say I'm looking forward to redoing all my strings, but hey, a solution is a solution. Cheers!

Comment: Well, maybe you dont have to redo them all - just take that method you wrote there and have it call the extension method that works, or use a find/replace with a regular expression to adjust your code. I'll add a bit to my answer to cover that

Answer (score -1):

I recently did the exact same thing using the below approach.

new class

```
 public static class RichTextBoxExtensions
{
    public static void AppendText(this RichTextBox box, string text, Color color)
    {
        box.SelectionStart = box.TextLength;
        box.SelectionLength = 0;

        box.SelectionColor = color;
        box.AppendText(text);
        box.SelectionColor = box.ForeColor;
    }
}
```

then on button click

```
 private async void btnCheck_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        rtbMessages.AppendText("My yellow text", Color.Yellow);
    }
```

Comment: Caution: using code that someone else wrote, without crediting them, is plagiarism - not something we're fond of here

Comment: @CaiusJard Even a "generic recommendation" like that needs to be supported with a reference to what seems to be the original. It is for example not obvious to me what you mean.

Comment: See the linked duplicate accepted answer with identical code ;)