# How to print RichTextBox text with text formatting?

Tags: c#, .net

I want to print `rich text box` data with both `fore color & back color`. For me, its very difficult. I use following code for font but changing color is difficult. Any one please help me.

```
 e.Graphics.DrawString(richTextBox1.Text, richTextBox1.Font, Brushes.Black, 100,100);
```

Comment: This is what you need   https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dotnet/articles/ms996492(v=msdn.10)?redirectedfrom=MSDN

Answer (score 0):

visit [Color different parts of a RichTextBox string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1926264/color-different-parts-of-a-richtextbox-string)
This is already answered

```
public static class RichTextBoxExtensions
{
    public static void AppendText(this RichTextBox box, string text, Color color)
    {
        box.SelectionStart = box.TextLength;
        box.SelectionLength = 0;

        box.SelectionColor = color;
        box.AppendText(text);
        box.SelectionColor = box.ForeColor;
    }
}
```

use like this

```
var userid = "USER0001";
var message = "Access denied";
var box = new RichTextBox
              {
                  Dock = DockStyle.Fill,
                  Font = new Font("Courier New", 10)
              };

box.AppendText("[" + DateTime.Now.ToShortTimeString() + "]", Color.Red);
box.AppendText(" ");
box.AppendText(userid, Color.Green);
box.AppendText(": ");
box.AppendText(message, Color.Blue);
box.AppendText(Environment.NewLine);

new Form {Controls = {box}}.ShowDialog();
```

also refer this https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/part-i-simple-color-syntax-code-editor-for-php-written-in-c/

Comment: Rakesh T.R Thank you. https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/part-i-simple-color-syntax-code-editor-for-php-written-in-c/ this link helps me to print fore color . How to print back color.

Comment: Thank you every one. I got it. Here my coding

Answer (score 0):

This is what you need:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dotnet/articles/ms996492(v=msdn.10)?redirectedfrom=MSDN

I face this problem a few months ago, and this helped alot!

How to use it:

Create custom richtextbox

```
    // C#
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Drawing.Printing;

/// <summary>
/// An extension for RichTextBox suitable for printing.
/// </summary>
public class RichTextBoxEx : RichTextBox
{[ StructLayout( LayoutKind.Sequential )]
    private struct STRUCT_RECT 
    {
        public Int32 left;
        public Int32 top;
        public Int32 right;
        public Int32 bottom;
    }

    // C#
    [ StructLayout( LayoutKind.Sequential )]
    private struct STRUCT_CHARRANGE
    {
        public Int32 cpMin;
        public Int32 cpMax;
    }

    [ StructLayout( LayoutKind.Sequential )]
    private struct STRUCT_FORMATRANGE
    {
        public IntPtr hdc; 
        public IntPtr hdcTarget; 
        public STRUCT_RECT rc; 
        public STRUCT_RECT rcPage; 
        public STRUCT_CHARRANGE chrg; 
    }
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    private static extern Int32 SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg,
                                            Int32 wParam, IntPtr lParam);

    private const Int32 WM_USER        = 0x400;
    private const Int32 EM_FORMATRANGE = WM_USER+57;

// C#
/// <summary>
/// Calculate or render the contents of our RichTextBox for printing
/// </summary>
/// <param name="measureOnly">If true, only the calculation is performed,
/// otherwise the text is rendered as well</param>
/// <param name="e">The PrintPageEventArgs object from the
/// PrintPage event</param>
/// <param name="charFrom">Index of first character to be printed</param>
/// <param name="charTo">Index of last character to be printed</param>
/// <returns>(Index of last character that fitted on the
/// page) + 1</returns>
public int FormatRange(bool measureOnly, PrintPageEventArgs e,
                       int charFrom, int charTo)
{
    // Specify which characters to print
    STRUCT_CHARRANGE cr;
    cr.cpMin = charFrom;
    cr.cpMax = charTo;

    // Specify the area inside page margins
    STRUCT_RECT rc;
    rc.top        = HundredthInchToTwips(e.MarginBounds.Top);
    rc.bottom    = HundredthInchToTwips(e.MarginBounds.Bottom);
    rc.left        = HundredthInchToTwips(e.MarginBounds.Left);
    rc.right    = HundredthInchToTwips(e.MarginBounds.Right);

    // Specify the page area
    STRUCT_RECT rcPage;
    rcPage.top    = HundredthInchToTwips(e.PageBounds.Top);
    rcPage.bottom = HundredthInchToTwips(e.PageBounds.Bottom);
    rcPage.left   = HundredthInchToTwips(e.PageBounds.Left);
    rcPage.right  = HundredthInchToTwips(e.PageBounds.Right);

    // Get device context of output device
    IntPtr hdc = e.Graphics.GetHdc();

    // Fill in the FORMATRANGE struct
    STRUCT_FORMATRANGE fr;
    fr.chrg      = cr;
    fr.hdc       = hdc;
    fr.hdcTarget = hdc;
    fr.rc        = rc;
    fr.rcPage    = rcPage;

    // Non-Zero wParam means render, Zero means measure
    Int32 wParam = (measureOnly ? 0 : 1);

    // Allocate memory for the FORMATRANGE struct and
    // copy the contents of our struct to this memory
    IntPtr lParam = Marshal.AllocCoTaskMem( Marshal.SizeOf( fr ) ); 
    Marshal.StructureToPtr(fr, lParam, false);

    // Send the actual Win32 message
    int res = SendMessage(Handle, EM_FORMATRANGE, wParam, lParam);

    // Free allocated memory
    Marshal.FreeCoTaskMem(lParam);

    // and release the device context
    e.Graphics.ReleaseHdc(hdc);

    return res;
}

// C#
/// <summary>
/// Convert between 1/100 inch (unit used by the .NET framework)
/// and twips (1/1440 inch, used by Win32 API calls)
/// </summary>
/// <param name="n">Value in 1/100 inch</param>
/// <returns>Value in twips</returns>
private Int32 HundredthInchToTwips(int n)
{
    return (Int32)(n*14.4);
}

}
```

And print eventHandler in form

```
// C#
// variable to trace text to print for pagination
private int m_nFirstCharOnPage;

private void printDoc_BeginPrint(object sender,
    System.Drawing.Printing.PrintEventArgs e)
{
    // Start at the beginning of the text
    m_nFirstCharOnPage = 0;
}

private void printDoc_PrintPage(object sender,
    System.Drawing.Printing.PrintPageEventArgs e)
{
    // To print the boundaries of the current page margins
    // uncomment the next line:
    // e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(System.Drawing.Pens.Blue, e.MarginBounds);

    // make the RichTextBoxEx calculate and render as much text as will
    // fit on the page and remember the last character printed for the
    // beginning of the next page
    m_nFirstCharOnPage = myRichTextBoxEx.FormatRange(false,
                                            e,
                                            m_nFirstCharOnPage,
                                            myRichTextBoxEx.TextLength);

// check if there are more pages to print
    if (m_nFirstCharOnPage < myRichTextBoxEx.TextLength)
        e.HasMorePages = true;
    else
        e.HasMorePages = false;
}

private void printDoc_EndPrint(object sender,
    System.Drawing.Printing.PrintEventArgs e)
{
    // Clean up cached information
    myRichTextBoxEx.FormatRangeDone();
}
```

Comment: Thank you. But it is not working for me. Actually I changed the font color and rich text box color using color dialog box. But when I click print preview option i got only black & white file. So my question is how to get that color in printing.

Comment: @Divya  seem like you have found your answer,  congrats.  Anyway,  i used this code and it do work really well.  It can print multiple colors and fonts.  So if you want something more complex,  you can give it another try.

Answer (score 0):

```
private void printDocument1_PrintPage(object sender, PrintPageEventArgs e)
{
Color backcolor = richTextBox1.BackColor;
Color theColor = richTextBox1.ForeColor;
Font theFont = richTextBox1.SelectionFont;
int x = e.MarginBounds.Left;
int y = e.MarginBounds.Top;
RectangleF rect = new RectangleF(x, y, richTextBox1.Width, richTextBox1.Height);
e.Graphics.FillRectangle(new SolidBrush(backcolor), rect);
e.Graphics.DrawString(richTextBox1.Text, theFont, new SolidBrush(theColor), x,y);
}
```