# Change Backgroud color of specific line in Textblock control

Tags: c#, .net, uwp, textblock

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Logs,Mode=OneWay}" />
```

In my UWP application, I want to change the color of lines based on the specific keyword in beginning of the line.

[image]

I need to change the lines background color if line start with word **WARNING**

Can anyone suggest how I can achieve this with code behind?

Comment: Hope we can't achieve this with TextBlock , please try to use ReichTextBox

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1926264/color-different-parts-of-a-richtextbox-string

Answer (score 1):

> I need to change the lines background color if line start with word WARNING

No, you can't change the background color of the line of text directly in the TextBlock Class. This is the same for [RichTextBlock Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.richtextblock?view=winrt-22000) and [RichEditBox Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.richeditbox?view=winrt-22000). What you could change is the Foreground color of the text.

For your requirement,what you could do is to put the Textblock into a border or something else that has a background property

Like this:

```
<Border Background="Red">
<TextBlock Text="warning ....."
           FontSize="10" />
</Border>
```