# RichTextBox Highlight All Instances of a Phrase

Tags: vb.net, richtextbox, selection, highlighting, colors

In VB.Net, is it possible to highlight ALL instances of a phrase instead of only a single instance of it, for example:

```
    txtView.SelectionStart = txtView.Find("ERROR: Invalid command entered.")
    txtView.SelectionColor = Color.Red
```

This would highlight "ERROR: Invalid command entered.", however if my RichTextBox text is:

ERROR: Invalid command entered. < Only this line will highlight

ERROR: Invalid command entered.

ERROR: Invalid command entered.

Alternatively, is there a way I can simply colour the line when I write it to the RichTextBox? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nope, there's is only one value for SelectionStart and SelectionLength.  Yes, you can use the SelectionBackColor and SelectionColor properties to colorize the text that matches.  You'll find sample code in my answer in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/455713/selectively-coloring-text-in-richtextbox/455858#455858).