# Colored Output into richtextbox not working

Tags: c#, regex, richtextbox

I have a function that should output colred text RichTextBox. All the matches should be red, and the non-matching text black. The following function to tries to change the RichTextBox content color as my entries are being inserted ( as worked in [Color different parts of a RichTextBox string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1926264/color-different-parts-of-a-richtextbox-string) )

```
public void OutputColoredMatches(String InputText, MatchCollection Matches, RichTextBox OutputBox)
{
    int LastMatchEndIndex = OutputBox.TextLength;
    foreach (Match CurrentMatch in Matches)
    {
        OutputBox.SelectionColor = Color.Black;
        OutputBox.AppendText(InputText.Substring(LastMatchEndIndex, CurrentMatch.Index - LastMatchEndIndex));
        OutputBox.SelectionColor = Color.Red;
        OutputBox.AppendText(InputText.Substring(CurrentMatch.Index, CurrentMatch.Length));
        LastMatchEndIndex = CurrentMatch.Index + CurrentMatch.Length;
    }
    OutputBox.SelectionColor = Color.Black;
    OutputBox.Text += InputText.Substring(LastMatchEndIndex, InputText.Length - LastMatchEndIndex);
}
```

The function adds the text that should be black after only after setting the selection color to black, and and adds the found matching text only after setting the selection color to red. Despite stepping through the code and watching it *correctly* insert the text all of the output is black.

I also tried to change to insert all (or portions of) the text, then change the size of the RichTextBox selection. Then set the selection color, this didn't work either. All of the text was either red or black at the end, despite my checking and double checking that the selection was starting and ending in the appropriate locations. (I tried something similar to: [Selectively coloring text in RichTextBox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/455713/selectively-coloring-text-in-richtextbox) ). Here is an another variation of the function where I insert parts of the text, then change its color. I also stepped through this on in the debugger and verified it was selecting items as I expected then setting their color, all the output was black:

```
public void OutputColoredMatches(String InputText, MatchCollection Matches, RichTextBox OutputBox)
{
    int SelPos = 0;
    int LastMatchEndIndex = OutputBox.TextLength;
    foreach (Match CurrentMatch in Matches)
    {
        SelPos = OutputBox.TextLength;
        OutputBox.AppendText(InputText.Substring(LastMatchEndIndex, CurrentMatch.Index - LastMatchEndIndex));
        OutputBox.SelectionStart = SelPos;
        OutputBox.SelectionLength = OutputBox.TextLength - SelPos;
        OutputBox.SelectionColor = Color.Black;

        SelPos = OutputBox.TextLength;            
        OutputBox.AppendText(InputText.Substring(CurrentMatch.Index, CurrentMatch.Length));
        OutputBox.SelectionStart = SelPos;
        OutputBox.SelectionLength = OutputBox.TextLength - SelPos;
        OutputBox.SelectionColor = Color.Red;

        LastMatchEndIndex = CurrentMatch.Index + CurrentMatch.Length;
    }
    OutputBox.SelectionColor = Color.Black;
    OutputBox.Text += InputText.Substring(LastMatchEndIndex, InputText.Length - LastMatchEndIndex);
}
```

To be more specific, if I had a regular expression 's', and an input text of 'asdf', this functions inserts 'a' into the outputbox. Then it sets the selection position to 0 and the selection length to 1, then the color to black. It then inserts 's', the selection position to 1 and the length to 1, and the color to red. Then it inserts 'df' sets the selection position to 2 and the length to 2 and the color to black. Then all the output is black.

I also tried a variety of things with the selection starting location and length then inserting text without having any effect. I think it is likely that I am doing something incorrect only vaguely related to the text box.

What else can affect coloring behavior that I may not be paying attention to.

Answer (score 0):

You arent making any selections to color, in the link you gave they define a selection before setting the color.

```
box.SelectionStart = jx;
box.SelectionLength = phrase.Length;
box.SelectionColor = color;
```

You will need to find and select the matches and then color them.

EDIT: I havent tested this, but it looks about right..

```
//set the start of the selection to the current end of the text box
OutputBox.SelectionStart = OutputBox.Text.Length - 1; 
//set the selections length
OutputBox.SelectionLength = CurrentMatch.Length;
//and finally set the color
OutputBox.SelectionColor = Color.Red;
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. According to the MSDN ( http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.richtextbox.selectioncolor.aspx ) and the other link I provided Inserted text also respects selection color. I have tried this, but I will try again and post that function. I think that something tangential is going on, like some property or feature of the text box affects its coloring without my knowledge.

Comment: I posted the second version of the function that selects text, then sets its color. The output is all black.